# How to remove old Docker containers

Tags: docker

This question is related to *[Should I be concerned about excess, non-running, Docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014263/should-i-be-concerned-about-excess-non-running-docker-containers)*.

I'm wondering how to remove old containers. The `docker rm 3e552code34a` lets you remove a single one, but I have lots already. `docker rm --help` doesn't give a selection option (like all, or by image name).

Maybe there is a directory in which these containers are stored where I can delete them easily manually?

Comment: **You should also consider cleaning orphaned docker volumes.** I often find that they consume much more space than old containers and  old images. Good script for removing orphaned docker volumes is available at: https://github.com/chadoe/docker-cleanup-volumes.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/chadoe/docker-cleanup-volumes can help you.

Comment: You can also use `docker run`with the `--rm` flag which would make the container ephemeral, removing all container files after the run.

Comment: I agree with @NemanjaTrifunovic . Pay attention. Keep this in your toolbok: docker volume ls -f dangling=true

Comment: With docker 1.13 (Q4 2016), you can also consider the new `docker system prune` command. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39860665/6309).

Comment: @VonC this isn't working for me at `Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec` :)

Comment: Use the docker management tool `Portainer `

We can manage`all the old containers, non using volumes and images` by using this tool 

Its a simple management UI for dockers 

`Please refer my update below on how to deploy the application`

Answer (score 1783, accepted):

Since [Docker 1.13.x](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1130-2017-01-18) you can use [Docker container prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/):

```
docker container prune
```

This will remove all stopped containers and should work on all platforms the same way.

There is also a [Docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/):

```
docker system prune
```

which will clean up all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes, in one command.

---

For older Docker versions, you can string Docker commands together with other Unix commands to get what you need. Here is an example on how to clean up old containers that are weeks old:

```
$ docker ps --filter "status=exited" | grep 'weeks ago' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm
```

To give credit, where it is due, this example is from https://twitter.com/jpetazzo/status/347431091415703552.

Comment: Thank you!
By the way, it is not possible to tag containers, is it? For instance, one could have a database image, of which an instance (container) might contain valuable data. Another valuable tool might be to flag a container as being 'used', thus protecting it from 'docker rm'.

Comment: note that I will put these comments in the issue that you mentioned

Comment: Similar command to remove all untagged images:

`docker images | grep "<none>" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi`

Comment: This solution works well if you want to remove containers depending on their age. What I'd like to do (and I'm assuming I'm not alone in this) is to remove everything that's not in the dependency graph of some specified container(s). I've found that during development of a Dockerfile, the number of containers is growing very quickly. Furthermore, just deleting everything is not ideal either in case you have some long running compilations in your dockerfile. If someone has an idea on how to handle this I'd be very glad for your input.

Comment: @MichelMüller when building an image from a dockerfile you can specify the `-rm` option to remove intermediate containers after a successful build.

Comment: @FreekKalter Interesting - but doesn't that mean that the containers are getting removed that the building process is using for caching? In that case it does exactly the opposite of what I want - I want to remove containers that no running container or tagged image is building upon, such that if I rerun the build it won't start from the beginning, yet I'm not constantly keeping intermediate steps that led to nowhere.

Comment: @MichelMüller the images are what are used for caching, so removing the containers won't effect that.

Comment: If you want to use awk for this consider this command if you want do rm all stopped containers (without a error because of the first line): `docker ps -a | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' | xargs docker rm`

Comment: Based on this comment id made a cleanup script to delete old containers of different ages. You can get it here:https://github.com/juanluisbaptiste/docker-utils/blob/master/scripts/docker_cleanup.sh

Comment: If you get permission denied errors, add `sudo` before docker on the last command:

`$ sudo docker ps -a | grep 'weeks ago' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty sudo docker rm -f`

Comment: If there is a lot of containers/images you can use ```docker ps -aq | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm```. The output passed to docker rm will be merged into one line so only one docker command will be executed. It's a little speed up.

Comment: I am using Mac OS 10 Yosemites and this solution doesn't seems to be working (even if I added sudo before the command).

Comment: It is worth to note that you can replace `grep … | awk` by just `awk`.

Comment: You should rather use: `docker ps -a --no-trunc | egrep '((weeks)|(months)) ago' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm`. It also removes containers that are months old (docker uses months after 12 weeks). It also avoids ambiguity.

Comment: This command intertwines mechanism and policy. Why should a weeks old image be removed while it's possibly still relevant. Furthermore, this command relies on scraping. using the "-aq" options is more future proof.

Comment: This should be the updated command for removing untagged images
`docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)`

Comment: @Ghjnut yours was the only one that finally worked for me on Mac, though I had to change it a little. `docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)` all the others that I tried refused to do anything, giving a message about 'dependant child images'. Whoever decides to run this, watch out because it removes absolutely everything.

Comment: DANGEROUS!!!! USE IT WITH CAUTION!
Due to the grep as second command, it will also return you lines where it says "created X weeks ago", so you could potentially end up deleting recently created containers!

Comment: Doesn't work on OSX get `xargs: illegal option -- -`.   The question doesn't specify Linux, so going with Ryan Walls answer below as it's more concise and works cross platform (linux and osx).

Comment: You should really just use docker container prune, should work on all platforms.

Comment: With the very latest Docker, use `docker container prune`. If you can't use the latest Docker, say if you are using the latest Minikube v0.21 which doesn't have the very latest Docker, use the simpler `docker rm $(docker ps -q --filter "status=exited")`

Answer (score 652):

Another method, which I got from Guillaume J. Charmes (credit where it is due):

```
docker rm `docker ps --no-trunc -aq`
```

will remove all containers in an elegant way.

And by Bartosz Bilicki, for Windows:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker ps -a -q') DO docker rm %i
```

For PowerShell:

```
docker rm @(docker ps -aq)
```

---

An update with Docker 1.13 (Q4 2016), credit to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) ([later in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39860665/6309)):

**`docker system prune`** will delete ALL unused data (i.e., in order: containers stopped, volumes without containers and images with no containers).

See [PR 26108](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26108) and [commit 86de7c0](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/86de7c000f5d854051369754ad1769194e8dd5e1), which are introducing a few new commands to help facilitate visualizing how much space the Docker daemon data is taking on disk and allowing for easily cleaning up "unneeded" excess.

```
docker system prune

WARNING! This will remove:
    - all stopped containers
    - all volumes not used by at least one container
    - all images without at least one container associated to them
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
```

Comment: this somehow doesnt work for me, but `docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm` works, (sudo may be needed)

Comment: what about `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` ?

Comment: @qkrijger, this doesn't change anything from your original answer, except for adding bashism. The problem is with command line overflow. xargs variant deals with it in a nice way. I would also add --no-trunk to docker ps to avoid (unlikely) id clashes.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko You are right, thanks for the elaboration. Also, good idea on the notrunc option. I updated the answer with it and will update my scripts as well ☺

Comment: @chuwy My docker installation 0.7.x has `-notrunc`

Comment: @qkrijger hm, that's right. They using -notrunc for <0.8 http://docs.docker.io/en/v0.7.3/commandline/cli/#ps and --no-trunc for 0.8 http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/reference/commandline/cli/#ps
And I didn't find any mentions about this in CHANGELOG.

Comment: be aware if you use data-only container, it will remove them also

Comment: @FUD like your command and add `-f` to force if needed, then it is `docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm -f`

Comment: I don't see the point with `--no-trunc` since `docker rm` doesn't need full IDs anyway.

Comment: @Pithikos the point is the very slim chance that two hashes start with the same 8 alphanumerical characters :). The point is that there is no point in not using the whole hash when you script anyway

Comment: I used to remove old images with the chosen answer, but for some reason couldn't (docker rmi <tag> erred with some weird tag, different than passed). Then I've used this command - it did "something", possibly removed dangling images? Anyway it fixed the first command - which effectively cleared my images repo ;)

Comment: Why docker doesn't have normal inertial command for this? like: `docker rm --all --force` or `docker rm-all-containers`?

Comment: I've tried many things, and this is the only one that worked for me

Comment: This worked for me on Win 8.1 with boot2docker.  I probably wouldn't like to run it with any real containers setup, I just wanted to clear out the testing stuff I'd created.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko, I am all for `xargs` - but still, no bashism was added in qkrijger's comment - or do you consider `$()` as bashism?

Comment: @maxschlepzig, I don't remember what exactly I was thinking when writing that comment, so let's consider it a mistake. By no means `$()` is a bashism, moreover IIRC backticks are considered deprecated and `$()` are the recommended way to go.

Comment: PowerShell version: docker ps -aq --no-trunc | %{docker rm $_}

Comment: From this post (https://gist.github.com/ngpestelos/4fc2e31e19f86b9cf10b): 
Power Shell option
&'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker' ps -a | foreach-object { $l = $PSItem.ToString(); $c = $l.Substring(0, $l.IndexOf(" ")); if ($c.ToLower() -ne "container") { $cmd = "c:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe"; & $cmd "rm" $c } }

Answer (score 425):

**Updated Answer**
Use `docker system prune` or `docker container prune` now. See [VonC's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-containers/39860665#39860665).

**Previous Answer**
Composing several different hints above, the most elegant way to remove all non-running containers seems to be:

`docker rm $(docker ps -q -f status=exited)`

- `-q` prints just the container ids (without column headers)
- `-f` allows you to filter your list of printed containers (in this case we are filtering to only show exited containers)

Comment: This should be the correct answer because it relies on docker to tell you which containers are no longer used, rather than assuming the text output format of $(docker images) will not change. Bonus points for spawning only one extra process instead of two.

Comment: You might want to add `-v` to avoid dangling volumes: `docker rm -v $(docker ps -q -f status=exited)`. See https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container for details about dangling volumes.

Comment: @rluba apparently in Docker 1.9 there will be a separate volume api for handling that problem. https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14242

Comment: Unlike the answer marked correct, @RyanWalls answer works on OSX as well as being more concise.

Answer (score 261):

[The official way](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/6112) is:

```
docker rm `docker ps -aq`
```

The Docker maintainers have indicated there will be no command for this - and you compose the commands like that:

> We have discussed this before and prefer users to use the above line without having to add additional code to Docker.

Comment: This is a bad solution though, because it'll also delete storage containers.

Comment: What do you mean "storage containers"? If you mean data-only containers which once upon a time were used to keep references to data volumes, those are no longer necessary because of the availability of `docker volume` subcommand, and named volumes.

Comment: Note that this won't work inside Windows Powershell. For that, this is a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23674294/1150683

Answer (score 133):

With Docker 1.13 (Q4 2016), you now have:

[**`docker system prune -a`**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) will delete ALL unused data (i.e., in order: containers stopped, volumes without containers and  images with no containers).

`docker system prune` without -a will remove (for images) only dangling images, or images without a tag, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-containers/39860665?noredirect=1#comment89860875_39860665) by [smilebomb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447867/smilebomb).

See [PR 26108](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26108) and [commit 86de7c0](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/86de7c000f5d854051369754ad1769194e8dd5e1), which are introducing a few new commands to help facilitate visualizing how much space the Docker daemon data is taking on disk and allowing for easily cleaning up "unneeded" excess.

```
docker system prune -a

WARNING! This will remove:
    - all stopped containers
    - all volumes not used by at least one container
    - all images without at least one container associated to them
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
```

As [wjv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336078/wjv) comments,

> There is also `docker {container,image,volume,network} prune`, which may be used to remove unused instances of just *one* type of object.

Introduced in [commit 913e5cb](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/913e5cb77bcb7134be2e9b1aaa7e63627285e676), only for Docker 1.13+.

```
docker container prune
```

---

2023: [Taiger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203458/taiger) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-containers/39860665#comment136492642_39860665):

> The correct answer for modern versions of Docker: "[Prune unused Docker objects](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/)".

Comment: Thanks for sharing - for this to become visible, I'm quoting you in the answer high up in the thread

Comment: As usual, add the `-f` flag to force the cleanup with no questions asked.

Comment: should be marked as the nowdays correct answer, most of the above were right back in time, but are nodays overcomplicated

Comment: Agreed, so much easier lately, up up you go!

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern versions of Docker.
https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

Comment: @Taiger Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 128):

**UPDATED** **2021** (NEWEST)

```
docker container prune
```

---

This - **2017** (OLD) way

To remove **ALL STOPPED CONTAINERS**

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

To remove **ALL CONTAINERS** **(STOPPED AND NON STOPPED)**

```
docker rm  -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Comment: downvoted, since this is for sure _not_ the way you do that in 2017 - whis would be `docker volume/container/image prune`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39860665/3625317

Comment: upvoted to counter the downvote because a) this answer was from 2016, and b) plenty of folks dont run the bleeding edge.

Comment: unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a (Windows10)

Comment: we can simply use this to remove containers by using filter option
NOTE: until=24h means 24 hours old, you can change it accordingly.

>> docker container prune --filter "until=24h"

Answer (score 110):

It is now possible to use [filtering](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) with `docker ps`:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -q -f status=exited)
```

And for [images](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/images/#filtering):

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")
```

However, any of those will cause `docker rm` or `docker rmi` to throw an error when there are no matching containers. The older `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)` trick was even worse as it tried to remove any running container, failing at each one.

Here's a cleaner script to add in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` :

```
# Use `docker-cleanup --dry-run` to see what would be deleted.

function docker-cleanup {
  EXITED=$(docker ps -q -f status=exited)
  DANGLING=$(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")

  if [ "$1" == "--dry-run" ]; then
    echo "==> Would stop containers:"
    echo $EXITED
    echo "==> And images:"
    echo $DANGLING
  else
    if [ -n "$EXITED" ]; then
      docker rm $EXITED
    else
      echo "No containers to remove."
    fi
    if [ -n "$DANGLING" ]; then
      docker rmi $DANGLING
    else
      echo "No images to remove."
    fi
  fi
}
```

*Edit: As noted below, original answer was for removing images, not containers. Updated to answer both, including new links to documentation. Thanks to Adrian (and Ryan's answer) for mentioning the new `ps` filtering.*

Comment: Note the real avantage of this - you don't accidentally kill off `storage` conatiners.

Comment: You can also use `status=created` to get ones that are not running and have never run.

Answer (score 50):

Remove all stopped containers:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | awk '{print $1}')
```

From the comment by [pauk960](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2113724/pauk960):

> Since version **1.3.0** you can use filters with `docker ps`, instead of `grep Exited` use `docker ps -a -f status=exited`. And if you use `-q` with it you can get container IDs only instead of full output, no need to use awk for that.

Answer (score 38):

If you do not like to remove all containers, you can select all containers created before or after a specific container with `docker ps -f before=<container-ID>` or with `docker ps -f since=<container-ID>`

Let's say you have developed your system, and now it is working, but there are a number of containers left. You want to remove containers created before that working version. Determine the ID of the working container with `docker ps`.

**Remove containers created before an other container**

```
docker rm $(docker ps -f before=9c49c11c8d21 -q)
```

Another example. You have your database already running on a Docker container. You have developed your application to run on another container and now you have a number of unneeded containers.

**Remove containers created after a certain container**

```
docker rm $(docker ps -f since=a6ca4661ec7f -q)
```

Docker stores containers in `/var/lib/docker/containers` in Ubuntu. I think extra containers do no other harm, but take up disk space.

Answer (score 33):

**Update:** As of Docker version 1.13 (released January 2017), you can issue the following command to clean up stopped containers, unused volumes, dangling images and unused networks:

```
docker system prune
```

If you want to insure that you're only deleting containers which have an `exited` status, use this:

```
docker ps -aq -f status=exited | xargs docker rm
```

Similarly, if you're cleaning up docker stuff, you can get rid of untagged, unnamed images in this way:

```
docker images -q --no-trunc -f dangling=true | xargs docker rmi
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is my `docker-cleanup` script, which removes untagged containers and images. Please check the source for any updates.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Cleanup docker files: untagged containers and images.
#
# Use `docker-cleanup -n` for a dry run to see what would be deleted.

untagged_containers() {
  # Print containers using untagged images: $1 is used with awk's print: 0=line, 1=column 1.
  docker ps -a | awk '$2 ~ "[0-9a-f]{12}" {print $'$1'}'
}

untagged_images() {
  # Print untagged images: $1 is used with awk's print: 0=line, 3=column 3.
  # NOTE: intermediate images (via -a) seem to only cause
  # "Error: Conflict, foobarid wasn't deleted" messages.
  # Might be useful sometimes when Docker messed things up?!
  # docker images -a | awk '$1 == "<none>" {print $'$1'}'
  docker images | tail -n +2 | awk '$1 == "<none>" {print $'$1'}'
}

# Dry-run.
if [ "$1" = "-n" ]; then
  echo "=== Containers with uncommitted images: ==="
  untagged_containers 0
  echo

  echo "=== Uncommitted images: ==="
  untagged_images 0

  exit
fi

# Remove containers with untagged images.
echo "Removing containers:" >&2
untagged_containers 1 | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm --volumes=true

# Remove untagged images
echo "Removing images:" >&2
untagged_images 3 | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi
```

Source: https://github.com/blueyed/dotfiles/blob/master/usr/bin/docker-cleanup

Comment: @BradMurray Thanks! You might also like these: https://github.com/blueyed/dotfiles/commit/12591ec823d408997819b354c7dc4ac3dfeb88eb

Comment: Does not work on OSX because of the `xargs --no-run-if-empty` option

Answer (score 15):

First, stop running containers before attempting to remove them

#### Remove running containers

```
docker rm $(docker stop -t=1 $(docker ps -q))
```

You could use `kill` instead of `stop`. In my case I prefer `stop` since I tend to rerun them vs. creating a new one every time so I try to shut them down nicely.

**Note:** Trying to stop a container will give you an error:

> Error: Impossible to remove a running container, please stop it first

#### Remove all containers

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Answer (score 12):

Removing all containers from Windows shell:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker ps -a -q') DO docker rm %i
```

Comment: I'll include this in my answer since that is first page. Thanks

Comment: *"from Windows shell"*? Do you mean *"using the Windows shell (CMD)"*?

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/HardySimpson/docker-cleanup

## Docker cleanup

A tiny all-in-one shell, which removes:

- Containers that not running more than one day ago
- Images that don't belong to any remaining container

Intend to run as a crontab job

### Feature

- It will remove all `<none>:<none>` images
- If the image has multiple repo:tag references to it, it will remove all repo:tag except with running a container. Actually it is a nature of "docker rmi".
- Many error message will be show on screen, and you can decide to `2>/dev/null` or not
- Learn something from docker-gc, and fix its problem (it can not remove image that has mutliple repo:tag)

Answer (score 10):

So, personally I recommend doing this as part of your deploy script for both images and containers, keeping only the most recent n containers and images. I tag my Docker images with the same versioning schema I use with `git tag` as well as always tagging the latest Docker image with "latest." This means that without cleaning up anything, my Docker images wind up looking like:

```
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID        CREATED         VIRTUAL SIZE
some_repo/some_image    0.0.5     8f1a7c7ba93c    23 hours ago    925.4 MB
some_repo/some_image    latest    8f1a7c7ba93c    23 hours ago    925.4 MB
some_repo/some_image    0.0.4     0beabfa514ea    45 hours ago    925.4 MB
some_repo/some_image    0.0.3     54302cd10bf2    6 days ago      978.5 MB
some_repo/some_image    0.0.2     0078b30f3d9a    7 days ago      978.5 MB
some_repo/some_image    0.0.1     sdfgdf0f3d9a    8 days ago      938.5 MB
```

Now, of course I don't want to keep all my images (or containers) going back to perpetuity on all my production boxes. I just want the last 3 or 4 for rollbacks and to get rid of everything else. Unix's `tail` is your best friend here. Since `docker images` and `docker ps` both order by date, we can just use `tail` to select all but the top three and remove them:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q | tail -n +4)
```

Run that along with your deploy scripts (or locally) to always keep just enough images to comfortably roll back without taking up too much room or cluttering stuff up with old images.

Personally, I only keep one container on my production box at any time, but you can do the same sort of thing with containers if you want more:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq | tail -n +4)
```

Finally, in my simplified example we're only dealing with one repository at a time, but if you had more, you can just get a bit more sophisticated with the same idea. Say I just want to keep the last three images from some_repo/some_image. I can just mix in `grep` and `awk` and be on my way:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a | grep 'some_repo/some_image' | awk '{print $3}' | tail -n +4)
```

Again, the same idea applies to containers, but you get it by this point so I'll stop giving examples.

Answer (score 9):

**See all the existing images:**

```
docker images -a
```

**See all the existing containers:**

```
docker ps -a
```

**Delete single image:**

```
docker images -a
docker rmi <IMAGE_ID>
```

**Stop single container:**

```
docker ps -a
docker stop <CONTAINER_ID>
```

**Stop multiple containers:**

```
docker ps -a
docker stop <CONTAINER_ID1> <CONTAINER_ID2>
```

**Delete single container:**

```
docker ps -a
docker rm <CONTAINER_ID>
```

**Delete multiple images:**

```
docker images -a
docker rmi <IMAGE_ID1> <IMAGE_ID2>
```

**Delete multiple stopped containers:**

```
docker ps -a
docker rm <CONTAINER_ID1> <CONTAINER_ID2>
```

**Delete images only in a single command:**

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

**Delete both containers and images in a single command:**

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

**To prune all containers:**

```
docker container prune
```

Comment: `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) || true && docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`, by adding `|| true` you will continue removing images even if there are no containers for removing

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

It forcefully stops and removes all containers present locally.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: In ubuntu 16.04, docker requires sudo, so you have to write `sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q)`.

Comment: as a plus, this also works in Windows under powershell!

Comment: @Elliott I think `sudo` is required everywhere unless you add your user to the 'docker' group.  I use ubuntu 16.10 without sudo by adding my user to the docker group.

Answer (score 7):

Remove 5 oldest containers:

```
docker rm `docker ps -aq | tail -n 5`
```

See how many containers there are left:

```
docker ps -aq | wc -l
```

Comment: Nice Job @Pithikos. I have added the answer that removes all the old containers.

Answer (score 7):

**Remove all stopped containers.**

> sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q)

This will remove all stopped containers by getting a list of all containers with docker ps -a -q and passing their ids to docker rm. This should not remove any running containers, and it will tell you it can’t remove a running image.

**Remove all untagged images**

Now you want to clean up old images to save some space.

> sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -q --filter "dangling=true")

Comment: Don't forget to delete docker volumes by specifying the -v option (sudo docker rm -v $(sudo docker ps -a -q))

Comment: Didn't look this up, but I guess the same as: `docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm -v`

Comment: This only works on Linux, not Windows... But `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)` works in PowerShell / Docker for Windows.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to add this simple answer as I didn't see it, and the question is specifically "old" not "all".

`sudo docker container prune --filter "until=24h"`

Adjust the 24h for whatever time span you want to remove containers that are older than.

Answer (score 6):

1. Remove all docker processes:

   ```
   docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
   ```
2. Remove specific container:

   ```
   $ docker ps -a (lists all old containers)

   $ docker rm container-Id
   ```

Answer (score 6):

**New way:** 
spotify/docker-gc play the trick.

```
 docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /etc:/etc spotify/docker-gc
```

- Containers that exited more than an hour ago are removed.
- Images that don't belong to any remaining container after that are removed

It has supported environmental settings

**Forcing deletion of images that have multiple tags**

```
 FORCE_IMAGE_REMOVAL=1
```

**Forcing deletion of containers**

```
 FORCE_CONTAINER_REMOVAL=1
```

**Excluding Recently Exited Containers and Images From Garbage Collection**

```
 GRACE_PERIOD_SECONDS=86400
```

This setting also prevents the removal of images that have been created less than GRACE_PERIOD_SECONDS seconds ago.

**Dry run**

```
 DRY_RUN=1
```

**Cleaning up orphaned container volumes**
     CLEAN_UP_VOLUMES=1

Reference: [docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc)

**Old way to do:**

**delete old, non-running containers**

```
 docker ps -a -q -f status=exited | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm
             OR 
 docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

**delete all images associated with non-running docker containers**

```
 docker images -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi
```

**cleanup orphaned docker volumes for docker version 1.10.x and above**

```
 docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm
```

**Based on time period**

```
 docker ps -a | grep "weeks ago" | awk "{print $1}" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm
 docker ps -a | grep "days ago" | awk "{print $1}" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm
 docker ps -a | grep "hours ago" | awk "{print $1}" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command to remove the exited containers:

```
docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a | grep Exit | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

Here is the full gist to also remove the old images on docker: [Gist to remove old Docker containers and images](https://gist.github.com/urodoz/8ff64c77ecfb27c7cb32).

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
# docker-gc --- Remove stopped docker containers

RUNNING=$(docker ps -q)
ALL=$(docker ps -a -q)

for container in $ALL ; do
    [[ "$RUNNING" =~ "$container" ]] && continue
    echo Removing container: $(docker rm $container)
done
```

Comment: for those that don't want to search for it themselves https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc

Comment: It's perfect. I have also write an answer that has the same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove only stopped containers. Stop all of them in the beginning

`docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`

Then you can remove

`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

Answer (score 4):

Try this command to clean containers and dangling images.

```
docker system prune -a
```

Comment: This is an amazing pro-tip!

Answer (score 3):

I always use `docker rmi $(docker ps -a -q)` to remove all images.

You can remove directory `/var/lib/docker/graph` when `docker rmi` failed.

Comment: Thanks for adding the /var/lib/docker/graph info

Comment: The questions was how to remove containers, not images.

Answer (score 3):

#### The basic steps to stop/remove all containers and images

1. List all the containers

   `docker ps -aq`
2. Stop all running containers

   `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)`
3. Remove all containers

   `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`
4. Remove all images

   `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

**Note:** First you have to stop all the running containers before you remove them. Also before removing an image, you have to stop and remove its dependent container(s).

Answer (score 3):

I am using following commands to delete **Exited** and **Restarting** docker containers

```
docker stop --force $(docker ps -a|grep Exited| awk '{print $1}')
docker rm --force $(docker ps -a|grep Exited| awk '{print $1}')
docker stop --force $(docker ps -a|grep Restarting| awk '{print $1}')
docker rm --force $(docker ps -a|grep Restarting| awk '{print $1}')
```

Using below command to remove images named as **none**

```
docker image rm --force $(docker image ls  |grep none |awk '{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove **ALL stopped** docker containers, run:-

```
$ docker container prune
```

You'll have to be careful with this command since it removes all stopped containers indiscriminately so make sure there's no **stopped/currently unused** container that you may still have use of.

A more precise alternative is to remove the container by ID. You'll have to first list the **stopped** containers using this command:-

```
docker ps --filter "status=exited"
```

You'll then copy the **ID** of the container you want to remove.
Thereafter, execute the following command that removes **a single** container,

```
docker container rm <container ID>
```

or the one below to remove **multiple** containers at once by running:-

```
docker container rm <container ID 1> <container ID 2> <container ID n>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Remove all containers created from a certain image:

```
docker rm  $(docker ps -a | awk '/myimage:mytag/{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr):

```
$ for CON in `docker ps -qa`; do docker rm $CON ; done
```

This is just a normal Bash command so it should work with EVERY Bash-compliant terminal.

Comment: Is the first `$` actually to be put into the terminal (or is it part of the prompt?)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen first `$` only means it's shell prompt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt

Answer (score 2):

To remove ALL containers:

```
sudo docker ps -a | grep -v CONTAINER | awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty sudo docker rm -f
```

Explanation:

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

Returns a list of containers.

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

Gets the first column which is the container ID.

```
grep -v CONTAINER
```

Remove the title.

The last pipe sends the IDs to `sudo docker rm -f` safely.

Comment: Wow. For a newbie user like me, that sounds a little bit complicated. Would you please add some instruction about what it has done and the pipelines. I would be thankful if you could check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068287/7310077), too.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I took the example from qkrijger and turned it into a clear all (stop and remove all)

```
docker stop `docker ps --no-trunc -aq` ; docker rm `docker ps --no-trunc -aq`
```

Comment: If you are removing the containers anyway, then `docker rm -f $(docker ps --no-trunc -aq)` is faster

Comment: True, but if you need it to go through proper shutdown to cleanup shared or reused resources (i.e. Attached volumes, correctly closed active connections, etc) then you need to call stop first. Great example, if you have a Jenkins container, then killing the container is a bad idea. You want it to save any unpersisted changes, warn logged in users, and, very importantly, properly stop all builds.

Comment: agreed, that is a very valid use case

Answer (score 2):

To simply remove everything that is not currently used by a running container the following *alias*, that I usually put into the `.bash_profile` on my Mac, will help:

```
alias dockerclean="docker ps -q -a | xargs docker rm -v && docker images -q | xargs docker rmi"
```

Whenever `dockerclean` is invoked from the command line it will remove stopped containers as well as unused image layers. For running containers and used images it will print a warning message and skip over it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Cleanup unused containers
unused_containers=$(docker ps -a -q --filter="status=exited")
if [[ -n $unused_containers ]]
then
  docker rm $unused_containers
fi

echo Cleanup unused images
unused_images=$(docker images | grep '^<none>' | awk '{print $3}')
if [[ -n $unused_images ]]
then
  docker rmi $unused_images
fi
```

Comment: When you are answering, it's best to have some explanation as to what the solution does rather than just a code dump, as otherwise the answer may be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
docker rm --force `docker ps -qa`
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using:

```
docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
```

to delete exited containers and:

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk "{print \$3}")
```

in order to get rid of all untagged images.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automatically/periodically clean up exited containers and remove images and volumes that aren't in use by a running container you can download the image `meltwater/docker-cleanup`.

I use this in production since we deploy several times a day on multiple servers, and I don't want to go to every server to clean up (that would be a pain).

Just run:

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw  -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw --restart=unless-stopped meltwater/docker-cleanup:latest
```

It will run every 30 minutes by default (or however long you set it using DELAY_TIME=1800 option) and clean up exited containers and images.

More details: *[Docker Cleanup](https://github.com/meltwater/docker-cleanup/blob/master/README.md)*

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script to remove both running and exited containers created longer than 2 days:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will kill and remove containers older than 2 days.
#
docker ps -aq > /scripts/containers.txt
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
oldate=`date --date="2 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d`
while read p; do
    cont=`docker inspect -f '{{ .Created }}' $p | cut -c 1-10`
    echo " Created date of $p is $cont"
    k=`echo $(( ( $(date -ud $today +'%s') - $(date -ud $cont +'%s'))/60/60/24 ))`
    echo $k
    if [ $k -ge 2 ];
    then
            echo "Killing docker container $p"
            docker kill $p
            echo "Removing docker container $p"
            docker rm $p
    else
            echo "Docker container $p is not one day old, so keeping the container."
    fi
done </scripts/containers.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This process contains two steps (stop and remove):

1. Stop the container that is being used by any running microservices

   ```
   docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
   ```
2. Remove all the containers

   ```
   docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
   ```
3. Remove single container

   ```
   docker rm container-ID
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I found the below command is very handy to stop and remove all the containers. You don't need to stop explicitly with another command if you are using the `-f` (force) flag as it stops all running containers:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following nested commands:

```
$ sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

This command stops all running containers.

```
$ sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

This command remove all containers.

Answer (score 1):

I use variations of the following:

```
docker ps -a | grep 'cassandra.*Exited' | cut -d " " -f 1
```

The first part lists all processes.

The second selects just those that have 'cassandra' followed by 'Exited'.

The third, removes all the tests after the image ID, so you get a list of image ids.

So,

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep 'cassandra.*Exited' | cut -d " " -f 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a Linux installation make sure you use [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). Also it's good to look for images that are months and weeks old:

```
sudo docker ps -a | grep 'weeks ago\|months ago' | \
    awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty sudo docker rm
```

Comment: make sure you read the installation instructions for docker on linux to avoid having to sudo

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker-helper from the repository https://github.com/kartoza/docker-helpers. After the install, just type `drmc`.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines of Bash will filter containers by some keywords before deleting them:

```
containers_to_keep=$(docker ps -a | grep 'keep\|Up\|registry:latest\|nexus' | awk '{ print $1 }')
containers_to_delete=$(docker ps -a | grep Exited | grep -Fv "$containers_to_keep" | awk '{ print $1 }')
docker rm $containers_to_delete
```

From [this post](https://esalagea.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/remove-docker-unneeded-containers-and-images/).

Answer (score 1):

This short script might help (compiled from previous answers)!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove dangling images

IMAGE_IDS=$(sudo docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)

if [ -n "$IMAGE_IDS" ]; then

    sudo docker rmi $IMAGE_IDS > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo 'Images removed' $IMAGE_IDS
fi


# Remove exited containers

CONTAINER_IDS=$(sudo docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)

if [ -n "$CONTAINER_IDS" ]; then

    sudo docker rm -v $CONTAINER_IDS > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo 'Containers remove $CONTAINER_IDS'
fi
```

Comment: The formatting of this answer is broken. Is it supposed to be one or two scripts?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, you should stop containers before removing them to avoid things like "this container is still running" kind of errors, so:

```
sudo /usr/bin/docker ps -aq |  awk '{print $1}' | \
xargs --no-run-if-empty bash -c 'sudo docker stop $@; sudo docker rm $@' bash
```

I keep an alias in my dotfiles like:

```
alias wipedocker="sudo /usr/bin/docker ps -aq |  awk '{print $1}' \
| xargs --no-run-if-empty bash -c 'sudo docker stop $@; sudo docker rm $@' bash"
```

Comment: You can pass the `-f` flag to docker rm to remove a running container.

Answer (score 1):

`docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)` will do the trick. It will stop the containers and remove them too.

Answer (score 1):

Removing older Docker containers is very easy.

List all the containers:

```
docker ps -a
docker ps (To list the running containers)
```

Once you hit `docker ps -a`, it will give you list of containers along with the container id (which is unique and combination of a-z, A-Z and 0-9). Copy the container id you wanted to remove and simply hit the below.

```
docker rm container_id
```

Your container will be removed along with the layers created in `/var/lib/docker/aufs` (if you are using Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner that removes all the exited containers.

`docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | grep -v CON | awk '{print $1}')`

If you want to remove ALL the images you can use something like this.

`docker rmi $(docker images | sed -n '1!p' | awk '{print $3}')`

Answer (score 1):

To delete a specify container

```
docker container rm container_id
```

If the container is running, you have to stop it before to delete it

```
docker container stop container_id
```

And this command is to delete all existing containers

```
docker container rm $(docker container -a -q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the docker management tool Portainer

We can manage all the old containers, non using volumes and images by using this tool

Its a simple management UI for dockers

HOW TO DEPLOY PORTAINER

Use the following Docker commands to deploy Portainer:

```
$ docker volume create portainer_data
$ docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer
```

You'll just need to access the port 9000 of the Docker engine where portainer is running using your browser.

Note: the `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` option can be used in Linux environments only.

Answer (score 1):

List all containers (only IDs)

```
docker ps -aq
```

Stop all running containers

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
```

Remove all containers

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

Remove all images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of your stopped container you can use:

```
docker rm <cointainer_id>
```

You can also use the name of the container:

```
docker rm <name>
```

If you want to get rid of all the stopped containers you can use the:

```
docker container prune
```

Or you can also use:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq -f status=exited)
```

You can use `-v` argument to delete any docker managed volumes that are not referenced any further

```
docker rm -v $(docker ps -aq -f status=exited)
```

You can also use `--rm` with the `docker run`. This will delete the container and the associated files when the container exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the containers using multiple ways that I will explain them in the rest of the answer.

1. `docker container prune`. This command removes the all of the containers that are not working right now. You can find out which containers are not working by comparing the output of `docker ps` and `docker ps -a`. The containers that are listed in `docker ps -a` and not exist in `docker ps` are not working right now, but their containers aren't removed.
2. `docker kill $(docker ps -aq)`. What this command does is that by executing `$(docker ps -aq)` it returns the list of ids of all containers and kill them. Sometime this command doesn't work because it is  being using by the running container. To make that work, you can use `--force` option.
3. `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`. It has the same definition as the second command. The only difference of them is that it removes the container (as same as docker prune), while the `docker kill` doesn't.
4. Sometimes it is needed to remove the image, because you have changed the configuration of the `Dockerfile` and need to remove it to rebuild it. For this purpose you can see all of the images by running `docker images` and then copy the ID of the image that you want to remove. It can be deleted simply by executing `docker image rm <image-id>`.

**PS:** You can use `docker ps -a -q` instead of `docker ps -aq` and there is no differences. Because in unix-based operating system, you can join the options like the above example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all containers then use

> docker container prune

This command will remove all containers

Why not clean whole docker system with

> docker system prune

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you can run this to stop and delete all containers:

```
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker ps -q') DO docker stop %%i
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker ps -aq') DO docker rm %%i
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker images --format "{{.ID}}"') DO docker rmi %%i
```

You can save it as a .bat file and can run to do that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On windows (powershell) you could do something like this:

1. $containers = docker ps -a -q
2. foreach ($container in $containers) {docker rm $container -f }

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to know the Container ID

```
docker ps
```

Then use the below command to stop it.

```
docker kill <container-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

A great auto alternative - containrrr/watchtower

It contains images auto cleanup, update and monitoring options

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  service:
    container_name: watchtower
    image: containrrr/watchtower:latest
    hostname: watchtower
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Bucharest
      - WATCHTOWER_CLEANUP=true
      - WATCHTOWER_INCLUDE_RESTARTING=true
      - WATCHTOWER_POLL_INTERVAL=86400
      #- WATCHTOWER_SCHEDULE=0 0 4 * * *
      - WATCHTOWER_LABEL_ENABLE=false
      - WATCHTOWER_MONITOR_ONLY=false
      - WATCHTOWER_NO_PULL=false
      - WATCHTOWER_NO_RESTART=false
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with this issue in a CI pipeline tasks and managed this with own solution. It is a self contained binary written in go and packages in a docker container as well.

For example simple usage for self hosted gitlab runner

```
# /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
# ...
[[runners]]
# ...
pre_build_script = "docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  --rm softkot/docker-cleanup --name=whatever --since 5m"
```

Have a look at public available [GitLab sources](https://gitlab.com/softkot/docker-cleanup/-/tree/master) and [Docker Hub Container](https://hub.docker.com/r/softkot/docker-cleanup)

Answer (score -1):

You can use some of the Docker UI applications to remove containers.

Sorry for advertisement, but I always use my own application to do the same things. You can try it if you are looking for a simple application to manage Docker images or containers: https://github.com/alex-agency/AMHub.

This is a Docker UI web application which is running inside a Docker container.
For installing it, you only need invoke this command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 -e DOCKER=$(which docker) -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock alexagency/amhub
```

Comment: Can you actually explain how one would accomplish what the original asker wants? They seem to be concerned that they have a lot of orphaned containers that it is tedious to fix. Adding another seems like a poor solution...

Answer (score -1):

To remove all the dockers, : docker system prune -a

Comment: Not accurate..from Docs : `Remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.`

Answer (score -2):

I am suggesting you to stop the images first and then remove.

You could go like:

```
$ docker stop $(docker ps -a)
$ docker rm $(docker ps -a)
```

Comment: Is it literally `$docker` (with the dollar sign)? Or is `$` the shell prompt?

Comment: $ for shell prompt. 
thanks for pointing out. added the space

Answer (score -3):

You can stop the docker container and once it is stopped you can remove the container.

Stop the container:

**$ docker stop "containerID"**   - you can also mention the first two letters of the container ID, and it works.

Remove the container

**$ docker rm "containerID"**    - again you can also mention the first two letters of the container

If these command do not let you stop/remove the containers, m,ake sure you have [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) access to docker host.