# How does one remove a Docker image?

Tags: docker

I'm running Docker under Vagrant under OS X 10.8.4  (Mountain Lion), and whenever I try to delete a saved image, I get an error:

```
$ docker rmi some-image-id
2013/07/15 hh:mm:ss unexpected JSON input
```

According to the `rmi` help, the proper syntax is `docker rmi IMAGE [IMAGE...]`, and I'm not sure what to make of that.

How can I delete an image?

```
$ docker version
Client version: 0.4.8
Server version: 0.4.8
Go version: go1.1
```

```
$docker info
Containers: 1
Images: 3
```

Interestingly, when I run `docker ps`, no containers show up at all. Running `docker images` shows four (4) `base` images and one (1) `node` image.

Comment: `docker info` shows the actual amount of images, you can try `./docker images -a -q  | sort | uniq | wc -l` it should be the same result (-a for all images, -q for only ids). `docker ps` shows only active containers, you can do `docker ps -a` to list all containers

Comment: Can you try to start docker daemon with `-D` option and the client as well? `docker -d -D& ; docker -D rmi <id>`. Can you also try `CID=$(docker run -d ubuntu bash); ID=$(docker commit $CID); docker rmi $ID`?

Comment: Alright, I've got one container with exit status 137 (not sure what that means), and `docker images -a -q | sort | uniq | wc -l` returns 3 (using `./docker` in that command returns "No such file").

Comment: Trying to delete the image in daemon mode returns the same error as in client mode. Running your second command (`CID=$[and so on]`) added five ubuntu images.

Comment: Can you try to build from source and try again? Or you can wait until tomorrow that v0.5.0 gets released.

Comment: Actually, that's the thing – I was capable of removing images on my original install (at this point I'm not sure what the command I used was). It stopped working, so I did a clean install, and now, still nothing.

Comment: Take a look at this pull request: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/1225

Comment: `docker stop myContainer & docker rm myContainer & docker rmi myContainer-Image:latest` did the trick for me (Docker desktop Windows). You don't need to stop *all* containers, just the one(s) for which you want to delete the image.

Answer (score 1039, accepted):

Try `docker rmi node`. That should work.

Seeing all created containers is as simple as `docker ps -a`.

To remove all existing containers (not images!) run `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`

Comment: If some of your containers are still running, you could run: docker stop $(docker ps -qa) to stop all containers. I think that removing a running container might not work, at least I remember I had problems with this. I might be wrong her... I have checked the man page and it supports my hypothesis: "-f, --force=true|false Force removal of running container.  The default is false."

Comment: Ah, i didn't know about the command for "remove all existing container".

Had written own:
docker ps -a | sed -r 's/^(\w+).*/\1/g' | sed -r 's/^CONTAINER//' | sed -r 's/^(\w+)/docker rm \1/g' | awk 'system($0)'


Thanks !

Comment: You know command-line options are badly designed when you need to use shell-specific features to achieve basic functionality.

Comment: To remove all exisiting images, you can use - "  docker rmi $(docker images -q) "

Comment: To remove all existing containers using windows powershell: 
`docker ps -aq | Foreach-Object { docker stop $_; docker rm $_; }`

Comment: If you want to remove all stopped containers, you can now use `docker container prune`.  Likewise, you can remove all unused images with `docker image prune`.  There is also `docker system prune` to clean up everything at once. By default it will only clean up dangling images, but has an option to clean up all unused images, can also clean up volumes, and has a filter option if you need to be more selective.

Answer (score 579):

The following are some of the ways to remove docker images/containers:

#### Remove single image

```
docker rmi image_name:version/image-id
```

#### Remove all images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -qf "dangling=true")
```

#### Kill containers and remove them:

```
docker rm $(docker kill $(docker ps -aq))
```

*Note: Replace `kill` with `stop` for graceful shutdown*

#### Remove all images except "my-image"

Use grep to remove all except `my-image` and `ubuntu`

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep -v 'ubuntu\|my-image' | awk {'print $3'})
```

Or *(without awk)*

`docker rmi $(docker images --quiet | grep -v $(docker images --quiet ubuntu:my-image))`

Comment: Addition: remove "dangling" images (images without tags): `docker rmi $(docker images -qf "dangling=true")`

Comment: the_image should be the image id

Comment: shoudl be `docker rm $(docker kill $(docker ps -a -q))`

Comment: "Remove all except" without awk: `docker rmi $(docker images --quiet | grep -v $(docker images --quiet ubuntu:my-image))`

Comment: @kolypto The "dangling=true" seems to end up not deleting non-dangling containers though.  Run again, minus the -f and dangling flag to remove the rest.

Comment: Is it just me, or is that last suggestion (Or (without awk)) not really working?

Answer (score 203):

## Delete all docker containers

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

## Delete all docker images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Comment: Remove untagged images: `docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk "{print $3}")`

Comment: http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/23-spring-cleaning-for-webdevelopers   `sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images | grep "<none>" | awk "{print \$3}")` and then to remove live release tags of 2015 (e.g. `live-20150121223`)  we can do  `sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images | grep live-2015 | awk "{print \$3}")`

Comment: To force it, you must write: docker -f rm $(docker ps -a -q)

Answer (score 77):

To remove an image from Docker using the image ID:

1. Get the list of all Images

   ```
   docker images
   ```
2. Identify the image ID of the image you want to delete, for example:

   ```
   REPOSITORY     TAG     IMAGE ID        CREATED        VIRTUAL SIZE
   kweku360/java  latest  08d3a9b8e166    2 weeks ago         5.733 GB`
   ```
3. Finally remove the image using the image ID (only the first three digits are required)

   ```
   docker rmi 08d
   ```

Comment: First one need to stop container and remove it , refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398087/how-can-i-delete-dockers-images

Answer (score 40):

#### Image:

1. List images

   > **docker images**
2. Remove one image

   > **docker rmi image_name**
3. Force remove one image

   > **docker rmi -f image_name**

#### Container:

1. List all containers

   > **docker ps -a**
2. Remove one container

   > **docker rm  container_id**
3. Force remove one container

   > **docker rm -f  container_id**

Answer (score 29):

Update, as commented by VonC in *[How to remove old Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-containers?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top)*.

With Docker 1.13 (Q4 2016), you now have:

**`docker system prune`** will delete ALL unused data (i.e., in order: containers stopped, volumes without containers and images with no containers).

See [PR 26108](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26108) and [commit 86de7c0](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/86de7c000f5d854051369754ad1769194e8dd5e1), which are introducing a few new commands to help facilitate visualizing how much space the Docker daemon data is taking on disk and allowing for easily cleaning up "unneeded" excess.

```
docker system prune

WARNING! This will remove:
    - all stopped containers
    - all volumes not used by at least one container
    - all images without at least one container associated to them
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but this doesn't directly answer the original question (which has already been answered, and whose top answer is still relevant).

Comment: I agree. However, since the title of this question is very generic this has sort of become a reference question, so I thought giving an update on the mechanism was in place.

Answer (score 25):

### Removing Containers

1. **To remove a specific container**

   ```
   docker rm CONTAINER_ID CONTAINER_ID
   ```

   - ***For single image***

     ```
     docker rm  70c0e19168cf
     ```
   - ***For multiple images***

     ```
     docker rm  70c0e19168cf c2ce80b62174
     ```
2. ***Remove exited containers***

   ```
   docker ps -a -f status=exited
   ```
3. **Remove all the containers**

   ```
   docker ps -q -a | xargs docker rm
   ```

---

### Removing Images

```
docker rmi IMAGE_ID
```

1. ***Remove specific images***

   - ***for single image***

     ```
     docker rmi ubuntu
     ```
   - ***for multiple images***

     ```
     docker rmi ubuntu alpine
     ```
2. ***Remove dangling images*** 
   *Dangling images are layers that have no relationship to any tagged images as the Docker images are constituted of multiple images.*

   ```
   docker rmi -f $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
   ```
3. ***Remove all Docker images***

   ```
   docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
   ```

---

### Removing Volumes

To list volumes, run `docker volume ls`

1. ***Remove a specific volume***

   ```
   docker volume rm VOLUME_NAME
   ```
2. ***Remove dangling volumes***

   ```
   docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -f dangling=true -q)
   ```
3. ***Remove a container and its volumes***

   ```
   docker rm -v CONTAINER_NAME
   ```

Comment: Why double `CONTAINER_ID`?

Answer (score 19):

**`docker rm container_name`**

**`docker rmi image_name`**

> `docker help`
>
> rm        Remove one or more containers
>
> rmi       Remove one or more images

Answer (score 13):

```
docker rmi  91c95931e552
```

> Error response from daemon: Conflict, cannot delete 91c95931e552 because the container 76068d66b290 is using it, use -f to force
>       FATA[0000] Error: failed to remove one or more images

Find container ID,

```
# docker ps -a

# docker rm  daf644660736
```

Comment: Is that an answer to the question?

Comment: Why `daf644660736`? How is that related to any of the previous?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, we have to stop and remove the Docker containers which are attached with the Docker image that we are going to remove.

So for that, first

- `docker stop container-id`  - To stop the running container
- `docker rm container-id`    - To delete/remove the container

then,

- `docker rmi image-id`       - To delete/remove the image

Answer (score 4):

For versions 1.13 and higher:

```
docker image rm [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
```

Comparing:

- the [documention](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/) of `docker image rm` and
- the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/) of `docker rmi`,

the `[OPTIONS]` seem to have no difference.

```
--force , -f        Force removal of the image
--no-prune          Do not delete untagged parents
```

From: [Introducing Docker 1.13](https://blog.docker.com/2017/01/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/)

> ## CLI restructured
>
> In Docker 1.13, we regrouped every command to sit under the logical object it’s interacting with. For example `list` and `start` of containers are now subcommands of `docker container` and `history` is a subcommand of `docker image`.
>
> These changes let us clean up the Docker CLI syntax, improve help text and make Docker simpler to use. **The old command syntax is still supported, but we encourage everybody to adopt the new syntax**.

Answer (score 4):

Docker provides some command to remove `images`.

> Show/Remove `Images`:

```
docker images
docker images -a # All images
docker images --no-trunc # List the full length image IDs

docker images --filter "dangling=true" // Show unstage images
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q) # Remove on unstages images

docker rmi <REPOSITORY> or <Image ID> # Remove a single image

docker image prune # Interactively remove dangling images
docker image prune -a # Remove all images

or 

docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images -a -q)
```

> Also, you can also use `filter` parameters to remove set of images at
>   once:

Example:

```
$docker images --filter "before=<hello-world>" // It will all images before hello-world

$docker images --filter "since=<hello-world>" // It will all images since hello-world
```

So you can delete that filter images like this:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "since=<hello-world>")
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "before=<hello-world>")
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete all of them using

Step 1: Kill all containers

```
for i in `sudo docker ps -a | awk '{ print $1 }'`; do sudo docker kill $i ; done
```

Step 2: RM them first

```
for i in `sudo docker ps -a | awk '{ print $1 }'`; do sudo docker rm $i ; done
```

Step 3: Delete the images using force

```
for i in `sudo docker images | awk '{ print $3}'`; do  sudo docker rmi --force $i ; done
```

Use the step 1 in case you are getting error saying it cant be deleted owing to child dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shell script to remove a tagged (named) image and it's containers.
Save as docker-rmi and run using 'docker-rmi my-image-name'

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGE=$1

if [ "$IMAGE" == "" ] ; then
  echo "Missing image argument"
  exit 2
fi

docker ps -qa -f "ancestor=$IMAGE" | xargs docker rm
docker rmi $IMAGE
```

Comment: you need `xargs -r` to make it work in the no matching container case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically/periodically clean up exited containers and remove images and volumes that aren't in use by a running container you can download the image `meltwater/docker-cleanup`.

I use this on production since we deploy several times a day on multiple servers, and I don't want to go to every server to clean up (that would be a pain).

Just run:

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw  -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw --restart=unless-stopped meltwater/docker-cleanup:latest
```

It will run every 30 minutes (or however long you set it using DELAY_TIME=1800 option) and clean up exited containers and images.

More details: https://github.com/meltwater/docker-cleanup/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

In my case the probleme is that I have tow images withe same name 
the solution is to add the tag after the name or the id

```
sudo docker rmi <NAME>:<TAG>
```

ex:

```
sudo docker rmi php:7.0.4-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Why nobody mentioned `docker-compose`! I 've just been using it for one week, and I cannot survive without it. All you need is writing a yml which takes only several minutes of studying, and then you are ready to go. It can boot images, containers (which are needed in so-called services) and let you review logs just like you use with docker native commands. Git it a try:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose down --rmi 'local'
```

Before I used docker-compose, I wrote my own shell script, then I had to customize the script whenever needed especially when application architecture changed. Now I don't have to do this anymore, thanks to docker-compose.

Comment: `docker-compose` is an orchestration tool and often impractical for use in simple projects. A standalone `docker` solution (not requiring the use of often-finnicky `docker-compose.yml` configs) is preferable in the context of this question. Additionally, there are many, _many_ good answers here already.

Comment: @Jules nobody mentioned docker-compose doesn't mean they are bad answers, and does not mean this is a helpless answer either. Docker native commands are not bad, but tedious and it requires quite a lot typing every time. "One is good, and two is too much".

Answer (score 0):

- First list all your images which are present by using :

  docker images

**For removing single image**

- Use docker rmi [image-name (or) image-id]
  // This will remove only that specific image

**For removing All images**

- Use docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)

Answer (score -1):

For me the following worked fine:

```
> docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG           IMAGE ID          CREATED             SIZE
debian       jessie        86baf4e8cde9      3 weeks ago         123MB
ubuntu       yakkety       7d3f705d307c      3 weeks ago         107MB
alpine       3.5           074d602a59d7      7 weeks ago         3.99MB
```

Then go ahead and remove an image by running some like these:

```
> docker rmi debian:jessie
> docker rmi ubuntu:yakkety
> docker rmi alipine:3.5
```

Answer (score -1):

List images:

```
ahanjura@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker images
```

> REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
>                               88282f8eda00        19 seconds ago      308.5 MB
>                               13e5d3d682f4        19 hours ago        663 MB
>   busybox2            latest              05fe66bb1144        20 hours ago        1.129 MB
>   ubuntu              16.04               00fd29ccc6f1        5 days ago          110.5 MB
>   ubuntu              14.04               67759a80360c        5 days ago          221.4 MB
>   python              2.7                 9e92c8430ba0        7 days ago          680.7 MB
>   busybox             latest              6ad733544a63        6 weeks ago         1.129 MB
>   ubuntu              16.10               7d3f705d307c        5 months ago        106.7 MB

Delete images:

```
ahanjura@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker rmi 88282f8eda00
```

> Deleted: sha256:88282f8eda0036f85b5652c44d158308c6f86895ef1345dfa788318e6ba31194
>   Deleted: sha256:4f211a991fb392cd794bc9ad8833149cd9400c5955958c4017b1e2dc415e25e9
>   Deleted: sha256:8cc6917ac7f0dcb74969ae7958fe80b4a4ea7b3223fc888dfe1aef42f43df6f8
>   Deleted: sha256:b74a8932cff5e61c3fd2cc39de3c0989bdfd5c2e5f72b8f99f2807595f8ece43

```
ahanjura@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker rmi 13e5d3d682f4
```

> Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 13e5d3d682f4 (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container 5593e25eb638

Delete by force:

```
ahanjura@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker rmi -f 13e5d3d682f4
```

> Deleted: sha256:13e5d3d682f4de973780b35a3393c46eb314ef3db45d3ae83baf2dd9d702747e
>   Deleted: sha256:3ad9381c7041c03768ccd855ec86caa6bc0244223f10b0465c4898bdb21dc378
>   Deleted: sha256:5ccb917bce7bc8d3748eccf677d7b60dd101ed3e7fd2aedebd521735276606af
>   Deleted: sha256:18356d19b91f0abcc04496729c9a4c49e695dbfe3f0bb1c595f30a7d4d264ebf