# How can I delete Docker's images?

Tags: docker

I've the following images:

```
alex@alexvps:~$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>              <none>              70c0e19168cf        5 days ago          1.069 GB
<none>              <none>              c2ce80b62174        8 days ago          399.2 MB
<none>              <none>              60afe4036d97        8 days ago          325.1 MB
```

and when I try to remove one of them I get:

```
alex@alexvps:~$ sudo docker rmi 60afe4036d97
Error: Conflict, 60afe4036d97 wasn't deleted
2014/01/28 00:54:00 Error: failed to remove one or more images
```

How can I remove them? Why is there such conflict?

Answer (score 499, accepted):

**In order to delete all images, use the given command**

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

**In order to delete all containers, use the given command**

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

*Warning: This will destroy all your images and containers. It will not be possible to restore them!*

This solution is provided by [Techoverflow.net](https://techoverflow.net/2013/10/22/docker-remove-all-images-and-containers/?q=/blog/2013/10/22/docker-remove-all-images-and-containers/).

Comment: Simple and straight. Also you below command to force remove images.
'docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)'

Comment: I got an illegal variable name error doing `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

Comment: The windows powershell equivalent is `docker images -q | %{docker rmi -f $_}`

Comment: First i used the cmd on @muheed [Answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30475249/2747020) to unlock the removing of some images: `sudo docker ps -a -q | xargs -n 1 -I {} sudo docker rm {}`

Comment: If container is already running use `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)

Comment: Windows Powershell for docker containers `docker ps -a -q | %{docker rm -f $_}`

Comment: As @alexyz78 notes below, you can now use `docker system prune`. So to wipe everyhing: `docker kill $(docker ps -q)` to stop containers followed by a `docker system prune -a` will remove everything - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309011/247708

Comment: @DavidMorales my edit fixes the problem you have
`docker rmi < echo $(docker images -q | tr "\n" " ")`

Comment: order should be like: 

sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q)

sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images  -q)

Comment: What I do is filter by image name first `docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep "<image-name>" | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Does `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` also delete image along with containers? or does it only delete containers?

Answer (score 110):

**Possible reason:**
The reason can be that this image is currently used by a running container. In such case, you can list running containers, stop the relevant container and then remove the image:

```
docker ps
docker stop <containerid>
docker rm <containerid>
docker rmi <imageid>
```

If you cannnot find container by docker ps, you can use this to list all already exited containers and remove them.

```
docker ps -a | grep 60afe4036d97
docker rm <containerid>
```

**Note:** *Be careful* of deleting all exited containers at once in case you use `Volume-Only` containers. These stay in `Exit` state, but **contains useful data**.

Comment: Actually, you would get a message specifying that. Maybe another image is based on this one? Try removing any images that you created from this image first.

Comment: I was able to remove the image with `sudo docker ps -a | grep Exit | awk '{print $1}' | sudo xargs docker rm` (thanks to https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/3258) and then with `sudo docker rmi 70c0e19168cf`

Comment: Be careful deleting images in `Exit` state. If you are using data volume-only containers they do not stay running.

Comment: awk can grep: `awk '/Exit/ {print $1}'`

Comment: Your commands throw this `Error response from daemon: No such container: ...`. It's hard to tell what has to be replaced, and what should I replace with. Don't use `...`

Answer (score 61):

The reason for the error is that even though the image did not have any tag, there still exists a container created on that image which might be in the `exited` state. So you need to ensure that you have stopped and deleted all containers created on those images. The following command helps you in removing all containers that are not running:

```
docker rm `docker ps -aq --no-trunc --filter "status=exited"`
```

Now this removes all the dangling non-intermediate `<none>` images:

```
docker rmi `docker images --filter 'dangling=true' -q --no-trunc`
```

> Note: To stops all running containers:
>
> ```
> docker stop `docker ps -q`
> ```

Comment: Thank you for this, I found this to be the cleanest implementation.

Comment: Be careful if you have data volume containers since they have "status=exited". This means that you'll lose all your data.

Answer (score 19):

In Bash:

```
for i in `sudo docker images|grep \<none\>|awk '{print $3}'`;do sudo docker rmi $i;done
```

This will remove all images with name "<none>". I found those images redundant.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's still very useful. Thanks.

Comment: make this command simple `docker images|grep \<none\>|awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi` , it may need `sudo` permission

Answer (score 19):

The image could be currently used by a running container, so you first have to stop and remove the container(s).

```
docker stop <container-name>
docker rm <container-id>
```

Then you could try deleting the image:

```
docker rmi <image-id>
```

You must be sure that this image doesn't depend on other images (otherwise  you must delete them first).

I had a strange case in which I had no more containers still alive (`docker ps -a` returned nothing) but I couldn't manage to delete the image and its image-dependency.

To solve these special cases you could force the image removal with this:

```
docker rmi -f <image-id>
```

Answer (score 15):

I found the answer in this command:

```
docker images --no-trunc | grep none | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi
```

I had your problem when I deleted some images that were being used, and I didn't realise (using `docker ps -a`).

Answer (score 11):

Since Docker ver. 1.13.0 (January 2017) there's the `system prune` command:

```
$ docker system prune --help

Usage:  docker system prune [OPTIONS]

Remove unused data

Options:
-a, --all     Remove all unused images not just dangling ones
-f, --force   Do not prompt for confirmation
    --help    Print usage
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply you can aadd `--force` at the end of the command. Like:

```
sudo docker rmi <docker_image_id> --force
```

To make it more **intelligent** you can add as:

First stop all running containers.

`sudo docker stop $(docker ps | grep <your_container_name> | awk '{print $1}')`

Now remove container

`sudo docker rm $(docker ps | grep <your_container_name> | awk '{print $1}')`

Now as a last step, remove docker image

`sudo docker rmi $(docker images | grep <your_image_name> | awk '{print $3}') --force`

Here in `docker ps` $1 is the first column, i.e. the Docker container ID.

And `docker images` $3 is the third column, i.e. the Docker image ID.

Note: In above commands `sudo` is used in case you might / might not have privileges to execute command. if it gives you error, try removing `sudo`.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Sunny's answer:

In order to **delete all images** on a Windows machine (with Docker for Windows) in a PowerShell window, do:

```
docker images -q | %{docker rmi -f $_}
```

In order to **delete all containers** on a Windows machine (with Docker for Windows) in a PowerShell window, do:

```
docker ps -a -q | %{docker rm -f $_}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, remove all the containers using the following command

```
sudo docker ps -a -q | xargs -n 1 -I {} sudo docker rm {}
```

Then, remove the image by its ID using the following command

```
sudo docker rmi <image-id>
```

Comment: It's worth noting in case this isn't obvious to some that this will remove all running Docker containers.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
docker image prune -all
```

**or**

```
docker image prune -a
```

Remove all dangling images. If `-a` is specified, it will also remove all images not referenced by any container.

**Note:** You are prompted for confirmation before the prune removes anything, but you are not shown a list of what will potentially be removed. In addition, `docker image ls` does not support negative filtering, so it difficult to predict what images will actually be removed.

As stated under [Docker's documentation for prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/).

Answer (score 4):

You have to stop/delete all unnecessary containers created on that images first.

Have a look: [How to remove old Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-io-containers).

After that use @marcell solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Remove all the containers**

```
docker ps -q -a | xargs docker rm
```

**Force remove all the Docker images**

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most compact version of a command to remove all untagged images is:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk '{print $"3"}')
```

Answer (score 3):

To delete some Docker image you must execute the following command:

```
$ docker rmi <docker_image_id>
```

So, to delete all Docker images you can execute the following command:

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Now, if you want delete all Docker images (including images that are in use), you can add the flag `-f`, for example:

```
$ docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically/periodically clean up exited containers and remove images and volumes that aren't in use by a running container you can download the Docker image `meltwater/docker-cleanup`.

That way you don't need to go clean it up by hand.

Just run:

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw  -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw --restart=unless-stopped meltwater/docker-cleanup:latest
```

It will run every 30 minutes (or however long you set it using DELAY_TIME=1800 option) and clean up exited containers and images.

More details: https://github.com/meltwater/docker-cleanup/blob/master/README.md