# Failing to delete Docker's images after terminating the container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, wso2-stratos

Im new to docker.
I created a container and deployed some images below.

```
stratos@Dev-PC:/media/sf_docker_vm/couchdb-cartridge$ docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
10.0.2.15:5042/couchdb-cartridge       latest              1bbc29d7cf4a        41 hours ago        785.2 MB
couchdb-cartridge                      latest              1bbc29d7cf4a        41 hours ago        785.2 MB
192.168.57.30:5042/couchdb-cartridge   latest              1bbc29d7cf4a        41 hours ago        785.2 MB
192.168.57.30:5042/tomcat-cartridge    latest              a25a79ecc37f        3 weeks ago         463.4 MB
tomcat-cartridge                       latest              a25a79ecc37f        3 weeks ago         463.4 MB
192.168.57.30:5042/mysql-cartridge     latest              ab1dac84c735        3 weeks ago         802 MB
mysql-cartridge                        latest              ab1dac84c735        3 weeks ago         802 MB
192.168.57.30:5042/php-cartridge       latest              809d2a1ebaf0        3 weeks ago         668.3 MB
php-cartridge                          latest              809d2a1ebaf0        3 weeks ago         668.3 MB
docker-registry                        latest              a158e64ae76a        5 weeks ago         596.2 MB
docker-busybox                         latest              2eb418e07fd5        5 weeks ago         4.964 MB
10.0.2.15:5042/docker-busybox          latest              2eb418e07fd5        5 weeks ago         4.964 MB
ubuntu                                 12.04               822a01ae9a15        6 weeks ago         108.1 MB
```

I wanted to remove 1bbc29d7cf4a image and it want let me to delete it saying:

```
stratos@Dev-PC:/media/sf_docker_vm/couchdb-cartridge$ docker rmi 1bbc29d7cf4a
Error: Conflict, cannot delete image 1bbc29d7cf4a because it is tagged in multiple repositories
2014/09/26 12:38:50 Error: failed to remove one or more images
```

Some how i follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398087/how-to-delete-dockers-images) and still im getting above error. Bellow is the steps i follow.

```
docker ps
docker stop <containerid>
docker rm <containerid>
docker rmi <imageid>
```

can someone help me to delete this images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is right in the error message:

```
cannot delete image 1bbc29d7cf4a because it is tagged in multiple repositories
```

Delete using the tags:

```
docker rmi 192.168.57.30:5042/couchdb-cartridge 10.0.2.15:5042/couchdb-cartridge couchdb-cartridge
```

Or just specify `-f` in the `rmi` command:

```
docker rmi -f 1bbc29d7cf4a
```

Answer (score 1):

On official docoments [removing-tagged-images](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#removing-tagged-images) description:

> If an image has more than one name, each of them needs to be removed before the image is removed.

```
docker rmi 10.0.2.15:5042/couchdb-cartridge:latset
docker rmi 192.168.57.30:5042/couchdb-cartridge:latset

docker images
docker rmi couchdb-cartridge:latset
```

Answer (score 0):

All containers referencing that image must be stopped and removed.

```
docker ps -a
```

Will show all containers, running or stopped.   Remove them first then the images should be able to be purged.