# If images in Docker are untagged, are they used at all or just orphans?

Tags: docker

Running the commands `docker images` and `docker images -a` results in the following outputs:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG        IMAGE ID            CREATED         VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu               14.04      9cbaf023786c        2 days ago      192.8 MB
$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY           TAG        IMAGE ID            CREATED         VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu               14.04      9cbaf023786c        2 days ago      192.8 MB
<none>               <none>     03db2b23cf03        2 days ago      192.8 MB
<none>               <none>     8f321fc43180        2 days ago      192.8 MB
<none>               <none>     6a459d727ebb        2 days ago      192.8 MB
<none>               <none>     2dcbbf65536c        2 days ago      192.8 MB
<none>               <none>     97fd97495e49        2 days ago      192.6 MB
```

Are the images tagged `<none>` of any importance? If not: why do they come with the tagged images I pulled? Do the sizes add up or are they just a repition? If so, can I delete them without any effect on my work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The image files are independent, and combine via unionfs magic to form a running container.
The images you care about are often tagged with memorable names.
You can delete the unused images, i.e. those not contributing to any image you care about.  I do it this way in bash:

```
function docker_rm_unnamed_images {
  sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images | grep '^<none>' | awk '{print $3}')
}
```

You can think of a docker image as a stack of 'layers'.  Each Dockerfile command adds an additional layer to the image.  It's important to realize that each of those commands creates a separate image file.  So the Dockerfile

```
FROM foo
RUN a
RUN b
RUN c
```

would be a stack of

```
image=1 (possibly pulled from the foo registry)
image=2 (after applying a to image 1)
image=3 (after applying b to image 2)
image=4 (after applying c to image 3)
```

It is likely that the foo image was composed of multiple other layers, so your final image is a stack of 4 or more images.  Each of those image files lives in your docker image registry.  Most of them are unnamed, because they correspond to a RUN command, for example.  Each of the image files 1-4 are probably fairly small (unless they correspond to a yum install p1 .. p100 for example).  Together they make up the file system of the container that you ultimately run.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found this way to delete them yesterday here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398087/how-to-delete-dockers-images
My questions are actually more directed towards an understanding: Are the images tagged '<none>' of any importance? Why do they come with the tagged images I pulled? Do the sizes add up or are they just a repition?

Answer (score 1):

To remove all untagged images, the additional options is needed:

```
docker rmi $(sudo docker images -a | grep '^<none>' | awk '{print $3}')
```

option '-a': show all images, including untagged images

Comment: Untagged images are called 'dangling'. To remove them in the proper docker way, please use command `docker images -qf dangling=true | xargs docker rmi`