# Why has Docker volume run out of space?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Dockerized database will no longer start because...

```
FATAL:  could not write lock file "postmaster.pid": No space left on device
```

There are hundreds of Gb available on my hard-disk although I do believe *something* has run out of space. This problem first cropped up after a couple of attempts at restoring a 45Gb database from backup. During that time my `Docker.qcow2` file ballooned to 60Gb. Does Hypervisor have some limit on the size of that VM file? Using Docker for Mac.

EDIT:
Just want to make clear that my usecase genuinely required that much diskspace but yes if you haven't tried `prune` then first try the most upvoted answer.

It seems to be a clue that I somehow get the same error when I remove these lines from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  - website_database_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

(and yes I sanity checked I was in the right part of the file by messing with other attributes)

Output of of `docker system df`

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              21                  16                  4.58 GB             -7.44e+09 B (-162%)
Containers          827                 3                   28.69 MB            28.69 MB (99%)
Local Volumes       5                   5                   57.02 GB            0 B (0%)
```

Comment: The default size of the disk for a VirtualBox VM is 20GB; have you set this to something bigger? Also, some folks have success here with upping their memory for Docker from 2048 (the default) to 4096

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459219/docker-out-of-disk-space as well

Comment: I didn't think VirtualBox was involved with Docker For Mac. Is using a VirtualBox software a way to get under the Hypervisor hood? I can't really afford to let it have more RAM. That other link is about boot2docker which I'm not using.

Comment: @Adamantish Have you checked if there is nothing you can remove with `docker system df`, for example? If there is nothing you can remove, then I think you will need to resize the qcow2 file

Comment: @Salem Thanks, I just looked. No nothing big that can be reclaimed. So is this a break of their promise? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#the-docker-for-mac-environment "With Docker for Mac, you get only one VM, and you don’t manage it. It is managed by the Docker for Mac application."

 So bypassing that is definitely not going to cause trouble?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `docker system df`?

Comment: @Salem Added. Hope it helps somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be a known issue which has a fix currently in beta: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371#issuecomment-262826610

Thanks to one of the hyperkit contributors for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 16):

Solution that worked for me from the docker-for-mac issue (hundreds of comments so to save you reading them all):

```
docker system prune -a
```

End result

> ....
>   deleted: sha256:c9d802a5c476d3100dfd62787867736f57177840605c6604ec845b9156e04603
>   deleted: sha256:f29af3b4c73780af53dd27f68cde554260185c89b3f26106491a7e29c1bca2f1
>   deleted: sha256:ea52b02280d9e96b22f25cc8f569c72e90ca4297f0c5ca3076f22e28d0c2f9b4
>   deleted: sha256:1e1c2966def79a1a2745bbb8589fbb6de6dcbbef049fa075f8974655f2ac0e7a
>   deleted: sha256:2e37924689f1bcd52df62e77fa37584fcb2d787dfa3787b71e7910f479455de9
>   deleted: sha256:ce5059dd22f090e710f834101b6c33b0567e6e8c13dcaed344f6e2d54678dea5
>   deleted: sha256:d48a21f58ae245ccdebc29d8f01fae42ce85842b4ea4de32902fb55a0a00ee03
>   deleted: sha256:5983b1164ccb0e6ac7a2dab6a6e29efaa11fcdf1350e91ff2aab919c31d63934
>   deleted: sha256:6049f38e8c033dea5e5b7ee7abd5b1af20e5c77f570752b560e49e51c35cc4df
>   deleted: sha256:d2987ea1ae6dfc8f2f3b07fd4e5802feab53e95c1590f12453166d2f57d2f301
>   deleted: sha256:8f3411639785500fb0133ca55d2639e0661ceb439417574adf084341905dd3d0
>   deleted: sha256:b7b7fbb077245d146b83458cb5099b22cf667f82342d7eed0b16f8e5f641149f
>   deleted: sha256:d0a6c2235a31bee1812d9db1afdf5ec5ff5eec53218e05d328db9c09bfded893
>   deleted: sha256:be2878c078e2df267e68687181f8373a31853f79086cac36edbf81ce07b40b28
>   deleted: sha256:fe4c16cbf7a4c70a5462654cf2c8f9f69778db280f235229bd98cf8784e878e4
>   Total reclaimed space: 53.43GB

NB: this also deleted some base images I hadn't used in a while so be prepared for some collateral damage.

Comment: That's great for many. Should be noted that if you really do need to actively use a lot of diskspace (as I did for a big DB) then you won't be able to prune away the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

*docker images -f "dangling=true"*

*docker rmi*