# Removing docker image errors "No such id" with a different image ID

Tags: docker

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker images
[sudo] password for parallels: 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu              14.10               525b6e4a4cc8        6 days ago          194.4 MB
<none>              <none>              4faa69f72743        6 days ago          188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              78949b1e1cfd        3 weeks ago         194.4 MB
<none>              <none>              2d24f826cb16        3 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              1f80e9ca2ac3        3 weeks ago         131.5 MB
<none>              <none>              5ba9dab47459        6 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              c5881f11ded9        9 months ago        172.2 MB
<none>              <none>              463ff6be4238        9 months ago        169.4 MB
<none>              <none>              195eb90b5349        9 months ago        184.7 MB
<none>              <none>              3db9c44f4520        10 months ago       183 MB
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker rmi 4faa69f72743
Error response from daemon: No such id: 2103b00b3fdf1d26a86aded36ae73c1c425def0f779a6e69073b3b77377df348
2015/03/16 20:32:38 Error: failed to remove one or more images
parallels@ubuntu:~$
```

Here, you can see that I've tried to remove `4faa69f72743`. However, docker insists that I am trying to remove `2103b00...`, and errors out because such image doesn't exist.

What could possibly cause this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398087/how-to-delete-dockers-images ? Slightly different error message, but still, check if you have any running containers that are using the image with `docker ps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the cause of it, but I've found a solution.

Here, `docker ps -a` shows exited containers with the image ID matching the problem hash.

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
1c538a69a522        2103b00b3fdf        bash                3 hours ago         Exited (-1) 3 hours ago                       sharp_mccarthy         
d9b683ddec73        2103b00b3fdf        bash                3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        nostalgic_davinci      
fcf8f628066f        2103b00b3fdf        bash                3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        drunk_rosalind         
06591014c89a        2103b00b3fdf        sleep 10            3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        sleepy_goldstine       
cb54fe012231        2103b00b3fdf        sleep 10            3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        compassionate_leakey   
de9cc4cbefe5        2103b00b3fdf        sleep 10            3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        agitated_brattain      
0ac0e70451cd        2103b00b3fdf        ps -a               3 hours ago         Exited (1) 3 hours ago                        berserk_goldstine      
a6cc821ab7a4        2103b00b3fdf        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        distracted_pare        
89f0c413787a        ubuntu:14.10        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        silly_hawking          
5388489a2df2        ubuntu:14.10        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        pensive_wozniak        
1a060874271f        ubuntu:14.10        pwd                 3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        determined_goldstine   
5bf4d049e3d2        ubuntu:14.10        pwd                 3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        angry_hypatia          
2033e10cb026        ubuntu:14.10        ls                  3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        desperate_poincare     
54f6f631cf17        ubuntu:14.10        ls                  3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        cranky_davinci         
c44eb12aeedf        ubuntu:14.10        bash                3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        high_darwin            
64f14a9cf537        ubuntu:14.10        ps                  3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        goofy_morse            
4b8f2516ddbd        ubuntu:14.10        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        high_ardinghelli       
0e3a3a6a8582        ubuntu:14.10        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        dreamy_turing          
49397f5bf47f        ubuntu:14.10        ls                  3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                        grave_hoover
```

Trying to remove the image was unsuccessful.

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker rmi 2103b00b3fdf
Error response from daemon: No such image: 2103b00b3fdf
2015/03/16 22:35:45 Error: failed to remove one or more images
```

However, I was able to remove the containers that were associated with the image.

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker rm 1c538
1c538
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker rm d9b fcf 065 cb5 de9 0ac a6c
d9b
fcf
065
cb5
de9
0ac
a6c
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
89f0c413787a        ubuntu:14.10        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       silly_hawking          
5388489a2df2        ubuntu:14.10        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       pensive_wozniak        
1a060874271f        ubuntu:14.10        pwd                 3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       determined_goldstine   
5bf4d049e3d2        ubuntu:14.10        pwd                 3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       angry_hypatia          
2033e10cb026        ubuntu:14.10        ls                  3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       desperate_poincare     
54f6f631cf17        ubuntu:14.10        ls                  3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       cranky_davinci         
c44eb12aeedf        ubuntu:14.10        bash                3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       high_darwin            
64f14a9cf537        ubuntu:14.10        ps                  3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       goofy_morse            
4b8f2516ddbd        ubuntu:14.10        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       high_ardinghelli       
0e3a3a6a8582        ubuntu:14.10        whoami              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       dreamy_turing          
49397f5bf47f        ubuntu:14.10        ls                  3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       grave_hoover
```

Finally, with the containers removed, I was able to remove the unused images.

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu              14.10               525b6e4a4cc8        6 days ago          194.4 MB
<none>              <none>              4faa69f72743        6 days ago          188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              78949b1e1cfd        3 weeks ago         194.4 MB
<none>              <none>              2d24f826cb16        3 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              1f80e9ca2ac3        3 weeks ago         131.5 MB
<none>              <none>              5ba9dab47459        6 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              c5881f11ded9        9 months ago        172.2 MB
<none>              <none>              463ff6be4238        9 months ago        169.4 MB
<none>              <none>              195eb90b5349        9 months ago        184.7 MB
<none>              <none>              3db9c44f4520        10 months ago       183 MB
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker rmi 4faa
Deleted: 4faa69f72743ce3a18508e840ff84598952fc05bd1de5fd54c6bc0f8ca835884
Deleted: 76b658ecb5644a4aca23b35de695803ad2e223da087d4f8015016021bd970169
Deleted: f0dde87450ec8236a64aebd3e8b499fe2772fca5e837ecbfa97bd8ae380c605e
parallels@ubuntu:~$
```

Hooray, unexplainable problems and solutions!

Comment: I suspect 2103b00b was a base layer for 4faa69f72743, so 4faa69f72743 couldn't be removed until 2103b00b was. 2103b00b couldn't be removed until all running containers using that image had been.