# Error running docker container: No space left on device: "/data/db/journal"

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Running containers form docker-compose on a Mac, this is the file

```
api:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/src
    - /src/node_modules
  links:
    - mongo
    - redis
  ports:
    - "3015:3015"
    - "5858:5858"
mongo:
  image: mongo:3.3
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
   - "6379:6379"
```

Running docker-compose up the mongo container fails and exit. this is the log file:

```
MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=7115a6cce706
db version v3.3.14
git version: 507a5b4d334c1b4bea8fa232fa6b882849608e97
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: debian81
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
options: {}
 ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
error creating journal dir /data/db/journal boost::filesystem::create_directory: No space left on device: "/data/db/journal"
exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::create_directory: No space left on device: "/data/db/journal", terminating
shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
now exiting
shutting down with code:100
```

The main complain it's about no space left for creating a dir but I can't figured out how to fix it.

Comment: try cleaning first docker containers and images -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398087/how-to-delete-dockers-images

Comment: I've done that before but the error remains

Answer (score 97):

I fixed the problem cleaning the old volumes with the next command:

```
$ docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Reference:
[docker-cleanup-volumes](https://github.com/chadoe/docker-cleanup-volumes)

**Update: 07/13/2018**

Docker now has a [built in command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/) for removing dangling volumes: `docker volume prune`.

Comment: running `docker volume prune` and freeing up some space worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 15):

I fixed the error by resizing the disk of docker:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/abe4de7ed3e951c3c37cdab0891914aca3f99fef/3.3/Dockerfile) for the mongo image shows that the `/data/db` path is using a Docker volume:

```
VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
```

If you run:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .Mounts }}' <your-container>
```

That will tell you where the data volume is being mapped on your Mac. If it's mapping to a drive which is low on space, you can start the container pointing to another location which does have space:

```
docker run -d -v <local-path-with-free-space>:/data/db mongo:3.3
```

Or add this to your Compose file:

```
volumes:
  - <local-path-with-free-space>:/data/db
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this problem on Windows and no amount of pruning, deleting, or cleaning up helped.

I had to use the **Whale > Settings > Reset > "Reset to factory defaults..."** option, which *did* ultimately fix it.

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea what caused the problem in the first place.  I'm paranoid that it's a bug/leak in docker itself.