# Getting "conflict: unable to remove repository reference"

Tags: docker

I am trying to delete a test image:

```
docker image rm test-image
```

but I'm getting

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "test-image" (must force) - container 4ca6d09c1103 is using its referenced image 133c9587889f
```

However, this container does not exist:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
fff756b1399a        rocker/shiny        "/usr/bin/shiny-se..."   6 months ago        Up 12 days          0.0.0.0:3838->3838/tcp   shinyServerBdl2
```

So: What is this about?

I've called

```
docker build . -t test-image
docker run -it test-image
```

to create the image from a `Dockerfile` but why can't I delete the image here? I also tried

```
docker rmi test-image
```

without success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker error cannot delete docker container, conflict: unable to remove repository reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907835/docker-error-cannot-delete-docker-container-conflict-unable-to-remove-reposito)

Comment: Please reboot your system, it works for me after reboot (I was using UBUNTU as a host machine)

Comment: @RohanJMohite Unfortunately I cannot reboot this machine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure that a container does not exist that is using the image. The container can be stopped and thus won't show when you run `docker ps`. You can do `docker ps --all` to view all runninn and stopped container.
In short, running the following should remove the image:

```
docker container rm 4ca6d09c1103
docker image rm test-image
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you are in dev environment**, and **if you want to remove all of images**, you can use this:

```
$ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) -f
```

**But don't do this in prod!**