# Docker does not free disk usage on Windows 10

Tags: docker

I have been playing around with Docker under Windows 10 (using Hyper-V virtualization). After having finished, I decided to remove all running containers and images using the following command:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

However it seems that the disk space is not reclaimed and I still have a whopping 38GB used by Docker on my ssd. What is the exact procedure to release that space? Looking at the my disk usage stats, I can see that that space is entirely used by the MobiLinux virtual disk...

Any procedure to shrink this on Windows 10 would be greatly appreciated!

Output of `docker volume ls` shown below:

[image]

**Edit**: this has been confirmed as a bug by the docker for windows team. I have opened an issue, which can be tracked here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/244

Comment: Did you use any named volumes?

Comment: No (not sure what's a named volume). Simply proceeded as indicated in the getting started docs...downloaded a couple of images and then started fooling around :). Also added my own software to the running container. However I would expect the disk usage to shrink once you delete the images/containers.

Comment: can you post the output of `docker volume ls` ?

Comment: added output screenshot of `docker volume ls` to original post

Comment: There are no volumes then.

Comment: this has nothing to do with volumes. If you delete all containers & images. Disk usage should be reclaimed

Comment: Removing containers wont remove named volumes. but this is not the case.

Comment: Would it help if you factory reset docker ? Or uninstall and install.

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-containers/39860665#39860665 ?