# How to install docker-engine 1.13 on debian Jessie

Tags: docker, debian, docker-engine

Following the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/) from Docker I get only docker-engine 1.12

```
# apt-cache policy docker-engine
docker-engine:
Installed: 1.12.4-0~debian-jessie
Candidate: 1.12.5-0~debian-jessie
Version table:
 1.12.5-0~debian-jessie 0
    500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages
*** 1.12.4-0~debian-jessie 0
    500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How can I install/upgrade to 1.13 ?

I need `docker prune system` https://stackoverflow.com/a/39860665/3313834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `docker 1.13.0-rc4` by running:

`curl -fsSL https://test.docker.com/ | sh`

Answer (score 3):

Docker has not released 1.13 yet. See the [release notes](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases) for details on new releases. To get on the RC of 1.13, switch to the [testing branch](https://test.docker.com/).

Comment: Docker 1.13 was released a few days ago: https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.13.0