# Docker old images cleanup?

Tags: docker

The output of `sudo docker images` shows images that were created ages ago, I don't see any use for them, `sudo docker system prune` does not remove them either.

How can I easily delete old images? Do I have to write a script to conditionally delete based on `date created` within the output of `docker images`?

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-containers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images) questions?

Comment: I agree, this is a duplicate. The referenced questions are specifically about container but have examples for images in them (as well as information about the newer `prune` command).

Comment: @scott Stensland this is not a duplicate question, in the docker world images and container are different

Comment: The two top answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images do not solve the issue. 

But yes I'd agree it's a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can filter images by created date, but you can use another image as a reference of time.

The flag (`-f` or`--filter`) with `before` shows only images created before the image with given id or reference.

For example, having these images:

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
image1              latest              eeae25ada2aa        4 minutes ago        188.3 MB
image2              latest              dea752e4e117        9 minutes ago        188.3 MB
image3              latest              511136ea3c5a        25 minutes ago       188.3 MB
```

Filtering with `before` (image1) would give:

```
$ docker images --filter "before=eeae25ada2aa"

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
image2              latest              dea752e4e117        9 minutes ago        188.3 MB
image3              latest              511136ea3c5a        25 minutes ago       188.3 MB
```

To Remove images before image1(eeae25ada2aa)

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images --filter "since=511136ea3c5a" -q)

dea752e4e117
511136ea3c5a
```