# Docker : error when delete running containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to remove  running containers and delete all downloaded images by using below commands:

```
docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm -f

docker images -aq | xargs docker rmi -f
```

But I got this

```
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
```

and

```
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
```

this is my environment

```
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:18 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21
docker-py version: 2.5.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

Is something wrong here? please help!
Thanks

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121627/remove-all-stopped-containers-docker-rm-requires-at-least-1-argument maybe useful for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first stop running container then remove them

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

For images try to remove dangling images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

To remove all images use

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `-r` with `xargs`, it means not to execute if empty:

```
docker ps -aq | xargs -r docker rm -f
docker images -aq | xargs -r docker rmi -f
```

Answer (score 3):

Following [Docker rm doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/#remove-a-link-specified-with---link-on-the-default-bridge-network):

> **Force-remove a running container**
>
> This command will force-remove a running container.

```
$ docker rm --force containerName
containerName
```

To remove **all stopped containers:**

```
$ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

For the Docker image:

In the [Docker Image doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/):

> If you use the -f flag and specify the image’s short or long ID, then
>   this command untags and removes all images that match the specified
>   ID.

Example:

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
test1                     latest              fd484f19954f        23 seconds ago      7 B (virtual 4.964 MB)
test                      latest              fd484f19954f        23 seconds ago      7 B (virtual 4.964 MB)
test2                     latest              fd484f19954f        23 seconds ago      7 B (virtual 4.964 MB)

$ docker rmi -f fd484f19954f

Untagged: test1:latest
Untagged: test:latest
Untagged: test2:latest
Deleted: fd484f19954f4920da7ff372b5067f5b7ddb2fd3830cecd17b96ea9e286ba5b8
```

In my personal experience when I need to force the deletion of a container I usually do:

```
docker container rm -f containerName
```

And, if I no longer need the image I use:

```
 docker image rm -f imageName
```

*Please note that the above command will throw an error if the image is still in use by a container.*

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you passing arguments incorrectly.
try something like that to delete all containers:

`docker rm -f $(docker ps -qa)`

And to delete all your images:

`docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that `xargs docker rm -f` retunrs nothing (you should try running just this) and therefore there is no argument passed to `docker ps -aq`.

PS - generally speaking, it is recommended to try running the expression that you'd use as an argument later, to see what it'd evaluate to, especially before deletion.