# Stop and remove all docker containers

Tags: docker

How can I stop and remove all docker containers to create a clean slate with my Docker containers? Lots of times I feel it is easier to start from scratch, but I have a bunch of containers that I am not sure what their states are, then when I run `docker rm` it won't let me because the docker container could still be in use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove old Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-containers)

Comment: Yea, I am not sure if it's a duplicate or not. That question you posted is about deleting old containers, while what I want to know is how to just delete everything, regardless of how old it is. But there is def overlap.

Comment: The question linked sure asks for old containers but the solution applies to ANY container you specify. So you could adapt that other solution to your case

Answer (score 439, accepted):

Stop all the containers

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Remove all the containers

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Find more command [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/)

Comment: unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a

Comment: Finally! Someone with a command that works for windows without an error! 
> Note: I ran these commands in Git Bash!!!

Comment: -a = all mostly ..

Comment: in the first command you dont need the ```-a``` flag. docker ps will list only running containers.

Comment: I would suggest using `xargs` for both of these, because if `docker ps -a -q` lists no containers, running either of those commands will fail because you gave it no arguments. Whereas using `xargs` will just not call the command.

Comment: The docker api responds in this case: `$ docker stop (docker ps -a -q || true`. 
`Error response from daemon: No such container: true`

Answer (score 95):

Docker introduced new namespaces and commands which everyone should finally learn and not stick to the old habits. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/), and here are some examples:

> Deleting no longer needed containers (stopped)

```
docker container prune
```

---

> Deleting no longer needed images

which means, that it only deletes images, which are not tagged and are not pointed on by "latest" - so no real images you can regularly use are deleted

```
docker image prune
```

---

> Delete all volumes, which are not used by any existing container

( even stopped containers do claim volumes ). This usually cleans up dangling anon-volumes of containers have been deleted long time ago. It should never delete named volumes since the containers of those should exists / be running.
Be careful, ensure your stack at least is running before going with this one

```
docker volume prune
```

---

> Same for unused networks

```
docker network prune
```

---

And finally, if you want to get rid if all the trash - to ensure nothing happens to your production, be sure all stacks are running and then run

```
docker system prune
```

Comment: `docker system prun` towards last is missing an `e`

Comment: IMO `docker system prune` is the real answer to this question

Comment: Although this is useful, none of these commands allow to stop all running containers, just clean up what already stopped containers left. So first you still need to stick to the "old habits" and execute `docker stop $(docker ps -q)` to stop them all gracefully, or `docker kill $(docker ps -q)` if there are some "reveld" containers that don't want to be stopped.

Answer (score 26):

```
docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm
```

or

```
docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm -f
```

---

`docker ps -aq`

1. `docker ps -a` or `docker ps --all` returns all containers and not only running containers
2. `docker ps -q` or `docker ps --quiet` returns container ids

`docker rm -f` or `docker rm --force` removes also running containers

Comment: Kindly provide brief details of the docker commands you mentioned for the users. Details are always helpful especially for students and junior developers.

Comment: This command kills everything. Nice for those who are in a hurry.

Comment: Note that this will throw an error if there are NO containers e.g. a deploy script run on a fresh instance. One would need to add a check.

Comment: Added `-r` like below to stop containers without error if docker ps -aq returns empty:
docker ps -aq | xargs -r docker stop

Answer (score 17):

One command line for cleaning all containers

```
docker system prune -f ; docker volume prune -f ;docker rm -f -v $(docker ps -q -a)
```

Answer (score 9):

We can achieve this with one liner (also removes running containers)

```
docker container rm $(docker container ls -aq) -f
```

What it does

`docker container ls -aq` lists container's ids only

`docker container rm $(..) -f` forcibly removes all container's ids

Answer (score 8):

The one liner:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

If you only want to do the running ones, remove `-a`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a good gist I use for this kind of thing:
From this link that people seem to not like (https://gist.github.com/bastman/5b57ddb3c11942094f8d0a97d461b430)

delete volumes

```
$ docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
$ docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm
```

delete networks

```
$ docker network ls  
$ docker network ls | grep "bridge"   
$ docker network rm $(docker network ls | grep "bridge" | awk '/ / { print $1 }')
```

remove docker images

// see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images

```
$ docker images
$ docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
$ docker images | grep "none"
$ docker rmi $(docker images | grep "none" | awk '/ / { print $3 }')
```

remove docker containers

// see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images

```
$ docker ps
$ docker ps -a
$ docker rm $(docker ps -qa --no-trunc --filter "status=exited")
```

Essentially you want to kill all your running containers, remove every image, uninstall docker, reinstall the version you want and that should be about as clean a slate as it gets.

Comment: Could you please post the commands instead of just a link to the gist? This will greatly help those users that can not follow your link to benefit from your answer. Also, some day that link may become broken and with it your answer become less usefull

Comment: Thank you, removed my DV

Comment: It's all good. Just trying to give back to the community, I've never actually answered these before. I guess all devs feel the call at some point?

Comment: That is great @Chris helping others is really honorable, as well as a good opportunity to reinforce your knowledge in the subject, as writing answers some times leads you to learn more on that theme or clear some old doubts you had. Just have in mind that your answers should be clear and consider aspects like this, which are required for good answers in SO

Comment: downvoted since massively outdated. There is no need for filter dangling=true any, prune is here

Answer (score 6):

stop containers:

```
docker stop container1_id container2_id containerz_id
```

delete all image:

```
docker system prune --all
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are concerned about shellcheck [SC2046](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2046) (in which case you would receive a warning for the command `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`) and you are using Bash4+ (to be able to use the `mapfile` builtin command), you can run the following to stop all containers:

```
mapfile -t list < <(docker ps -q)
[[ ${#list[@]} -gt 0 ]] && docker container stop "${list[@]}"
```

**The reasoning:**

- `docker ps -q` returns all active containers ids
- `mapfile` stores the resulting container ids in the `list` array
- `[[ ${#list[@]} -gt 0 ]]` tests if the `list` array has 1 or more elements to execute the next command
- `docker container stop "${list[@]}"` stops all containers whose ids are stored in the `list`array (will only run if the array has items)

Similarly, to remove all stopped containers:

```
mapfile -t list < <(docker ps -aq)
[[ ${#list[@]} -gt 0 ]] && docker container rm "${list[@]}"
```

(`docker ps -aq` returns all container ids, even from stopped containers)

If you want to stop and remove all containers, you can run the above commands sequentially (first `stop`, then `rm`).

Alternatively, you can run only the the commands to remove the containers with `rm --force`, but keep in mind that this will send [SIGKILL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_rm/), so running `stop`first and then `rm` is advisable (`stop` sends [SIGTERM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/), unless it times out, in which case it sends SIGKILL).

Comment: that's to accomodate spaces in container names?

Comment: @kjones If you use shellcheck you receive a warning with unquotted `$()` because "When command expansions are unquoted, word splitting and globbing will occur". In the case of docker container ids there's no such problem, so you can just disable the rule, but if you don't want to disable the rule, you can use the alternative way I posted. It does the same thing, although there is more code, so you might prefer just `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`, but I try to avoid unescaped quotes if there is an alternative, even if I know that there's no problem in this specific case.

Comment: i see, thank you for the follow up explanation

Answer (score 3):

This will kill all docker containers

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove all Docker images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -aq)
```

Answer (score 0):

> then when I run docker rm it won't let me because the docker container could still be in use.

The steps I would suggest are in following order,
1. Try to remove

```
docker rm <container-id>
```

2. rm doesn't work, use stop

```
docker stop <container-id>
```

3. stop doesn't work? try kill

```
docker kill <container-id>
```

4. stop worked but still container is there? try prune to remove all the stopped container forcefully

```
docker container prune -f
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer on the spirit of [Pankaj Rastogi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912521/pankaj-rastogi) comment, in one of the answers.

1. create a list of all containers and store them in a text file

`docker ps > containers.txt`

2. pass the `CONTAINER ID`s to `docker rm` one by one.

`cat containers.txt | tail -n +2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs -I{} docker rm {}`.

The latter lists all container entries, which start with a *container id*. Entries are separated by space and therefore, `tail -n +2` skips the first line which is headers, `cut -d ' ' -f 1`, splits every line by space and takes *the first* line entry, which is the container id and `xargs -I{} docker rm {}` removes the container with the specific id.

**NOTES**:

- the above works also for `udocker`.
- these commands, *remove all images*. If you want to inly remove some images, you can perhaps use a `grep` step, a bit before `xargs`, in order to filter out some of them.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at a combination of `docker ps` and `xargs` that cleanly stops and removes all containers. Bonus: it is configurable so you can do other things if you want to.

```
echo $(docker ps -a -q)|xargs -i sh -c 'docker stop {}; docker rm {};'
```

**Explanation:**

`docker ps -a -q` List containers

- -a, --all[=false]      Show all containers (default shows just running)
- -q, --quiet[=false]      Only display container IDs

`$()` The command substitution expands to the output of commands. These commands are executed in a subshell, and their stdout data is what the substitution syntax expands to.

`echo $(docker ps -a -q)` print the substituted output from `docker ps`. Without this the shell will fail by attempting to execute the ID of the first container as a shell command. (e.g. "<container-id>: command not found")

`|` creates a pipe, a unidirectional data channel that can be used for interprocess communication.

`xargs -i` build and execute command lines from standard input

- -i[replace-str], --replace[=replace-str]
  This option is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is specified.  If the replace-str argument is missing, the effect is the same as -I{}.  This option is deprecated; use -I instead.

`sh -c` dash — command interpreter (shell) (dash is the standard command interpreter for the system.)

- -c               Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set from the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining argument operands.

`'docker stop {}; docker rm {};'` the shell command to execute. `{}` represents each container ID output from the earlier `docker ps -a -q` command.

Answer (score -1):

In ubuntu I just killed all processes when other solutions didn't work.

```
$ ps aux | grep docker
$ sudo kill {enter process id here}
```

I do not recommend doing this way.I was on reinstalling your OS, when these command saved some time for fixing my issues with containers.

Comment: of if you want to stop/remove matching containers: docker ps | grep 'localstack\|postgres' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm -f