# How to kill dockerd -h fd// processes?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

Everytime I restart, I see loads of `dockerd -h fd//` processes when I run `htop` on ubuntu

I want to kill all of these processes (I have no idea why they're being run upon restart, but they're massively reducing my cpu performance.)

I tried every suggestion here [Stop and remove all docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357771/stop-and-remove-all-docker-containers) but nothing worked: the processes are still running.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First verify if you do not have containers that are still running :`docker container ps`, if you have containers that are still running stop them `docker stop container1 container2` or even `docker stop $(docker ps -q)`and verify if the cpu performance issue persists.

Then verify the status of docker service: `sudo systemctl status docker` here you can see different things that may help you :
[image]

Afterwards you can restart/stop and even disable the auto-restart of the docker daemon if you want :

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl disable docker
```

And if you want to start the service again at boot time `sudo systemctl enable docker` and verify if the problem persists.

PS: If you do not have `systemctl`, use the `service` command.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the proccess of the docker containers by using :

1 - docker ps -a

and then stop :

2- docker stop Container-ID

and then you can remove it :

3- docker rm Container-ID