# Run a container from an image and shell into it in one step? (i.e. docker run and docker exec in single command)

Tags: docker

I often do the following:

```
docker run -dt myimage
docker ps # This step gives the container id necessary for next step
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
```

Ideally I'd like to do it all in one line

```
docker run -dt myimage && docker exec -it <id> bash
```

but I don't know how to get the container id to `docker exec` without looking it up in a separate step.

#### Question

Is there a one-liner to run an image and shell into its container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a name for the running container and reference it that way.

```
docker run --name mycontainer -d myimage
docker exec -it mycontainer bash
```

You can also spawn a container and jump right into a shell.

```
docker run --name mycontainer --rm --entrypoint="" -it myimage bash
```

Or, you can run a single command inside the container and then exit.

```
docker run --name mycontainer --rm --entrypoint="" myimage echo "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

To take @GarretHyde's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74635277/5783745) a little further, here's a nice sequence of commands (that can be run as a single line with a few `&&`s) and will avoid any `The container name xxxx is already in use` errors:

```bash
{ docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) } || {} && \
docker container prune -f && \
docker build -t myimage . && \
docker run --name mycontainer -dt myimage && \
docker exec -it mycontainer bash
```

**Warning**

The `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` part will [stop **all** running containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51316176/5783745)

AND

The `docker container prune -f` will **remove** all stopped containers

So please be careful and make sure you're okay with both of those things happening before using this.

#### Notes

- A nice benefit to this is you can edit a Dockerfile then pres <kbd>Up</kbd> in the terminal and hit enter to rerun the command which will rebuild/run/shell into the new container.