# How to remove docker containers that are not running?

Tags: docker

It's possible to remove containers that aren't running?

I know that for example, this will remove containers from created images

```
docker rm `docker ps -q -f status=exited`
```

But I would like to know how I can remove those that are not running

Comment: You can use the command `docker container list --all` to see all the container no matter the state, and then use the command `docker rm containerName` to delete the container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove old Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236796/how-to-remove-old-docker-containers)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the `docker container prune` command, it will remove all stopped containers. You can read more about this command in the official docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/.

Similarly Docker has commands for `docker network prune`, `docker image prune` and `docker volume prune` to prune networks, images and volumes.

I use `docker system prune` most of the time, it cleans unused containers, plus networks and dangling images.

If I want to clean volumes with the system components, then I use `docker system prune --volumes`. In this case unused volumes will be removed, too, so be careful, you may loose data.

Comment: How do you remove a specific container that's not running and its volume?

Answer (score 2):

Also, to delete a specific container along with its volumes (as [@Harlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384545/harlin) questioned) you can use the following command: `docker rm --volumes container-name`. Official doc here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/#volumes