# A Simple Docker command does not work on Windows 10

Tags: docker

I want to remove all containers

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

or
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

I'm getting the following message

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker rm --help'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$()` is not Windows syntax. Would probably work on Linux and Mac but not on windows. Therefore it would be better to use docker only command - `prune`. So to remove all stopped containers you can do:

```
docker container prune
```

More info can be found  at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17237701/7489397)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```