# List only stopped Docker containers

Tags: docker, containers

Docker gives you a way of listing running containers or all containers including stopped ones.

This can be done by:

```
$ docker ps # To list running containers
```

Or by

```
$ docker ps -a # To list running and stopped containers
```

Do we have a way of only listing containers that have been stopped?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

Only stopped containers can be listed using:

```
docker ps --filter "status=exited"
```

or

```
docker ps -f "status=exited"
```

Comment: Also, you can filter them with `grep` for example `docker ps -a | grep Exited` or something like that.

Comment: Cool, now I can remove stopped containers with `docker rm $(docker ps --filter "status=exited" -q)`

Comment: better yet create an alias in your bash profile and use a shorter keyword/command to clean up stopped containers

Comment: "docker container prune" can be used since 1.25 I believe to remove stopped containers

Answer (score 72):

The typical command is:

```
docker container ls -f 'status=exited'
```

However, this will only list one of the possible non-running statuses. Here's a list of all possible statuses:

- created
- restarting
- running
- removing
- paused
- exited
- dead

You can filter on multiple statuses by passing multiple filters on the status:

```
docker container ls -f 'status=exited' -f 'status=dead' -f 'status=created'
```

If you are integrating this with an automatic cleanup script, you can chain one command to another with some bash syntax, output just the container id's with `-q`, and you can also limit to just the containers that exited successfully with an exit code filter:

```
docker container rm $(docker container ls -q -f 'status=exited' -f 'exited=0')
```

For more details on filters you can use, see Docker's documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering

Comment: Shame https://docs.docker.com/config/filter/ mentions the `!=` 'not equal' operator, but not for the `ps` subcommand.  This can be more easily achieved using the denylist strategy and the `jq` external tool though with docker's full container list json output: `docker ps --all --format '{{json .}}' | jq -rs 'map(select(.State != "running"))'`

Answer (score 28):

```
docker container list -f "status=exited"
```

or

```
docker container ls -f "status=exited"
```

or

```
 docker ps -f "status=exited"
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in BMitch's answer, there is more than one status for containers that are not running. Unfortunately, Docker doesn't (yet) support filters that exclude rather than include terms, but `grep` can be used with `-v` to perform this task. For example:

```bash
docker ps -a | grep -v 'Up'
```

or perhaps (for a slightly different use case):

```bash
docker ps -a | grep -v 'healthy'
```

The drawback of this approach is, of course, that the term `grep` filters on ("Up", for example) has to be present in the `docker ps` output, so `docker ps -q`, for example, would not be possible (and therefore piping the listed containers into a different command becomes problematic).

If you just want the filtered container IDs (the equivalent to `docker ps -q`), then the following may work for you:

```bash
docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Status}}" | grep -v 'Up' | cut -f1 -d":"
```

This creates output with the hex ID and status, filters the result and then cuts off everything after the ID from each resulting line.