# Why is Config.User an empty string when I inspect a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I pulled and ran the Docker container [jcsilva/docker-kaldi-gstreamer-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/jcsilva/docker-kaldi-gstreamer-server/):

```
docker pull jcsilva/docker-kaldi-gstreamer-server
docker run -it -p 8080:80 -v /media/kaldi_models:/opt/models jcsilva/docker-kaldi-gstreamer-server:latest /bin/bash
```

I can see it running:

```
username@server:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                     NAMES
24f598fd5019        jcsilva/docker-kaldi-gstreamer-server:latest   "/bin/bash"              12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
```

When I inspect it:

```
username@server:~$ docker inspect 24f598fd501911f32e10884ed3f86547e05a031f0d31324badc40c5fb5ed732a > inspection.json
```

I see in the `inspection.json`:

```
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "24f598fd5019",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",                       <-- Why is User an empty string?
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "80/tcp": {}
        },
```

What could explain that Config.User is an empty string?

I use Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24 on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64).

Answer (score 3):

Because the `Dockerfile` doesn't have a [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) directive, most likely. Why are you expecting it to have one?

Of all of the containers running on my PC right now, only one has a user, and that's `grafana`, because that's what's in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L36). It's not the  user (me: `roger`) that launched it.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, got it, I mistakenly thought Config.User would be the user that launched the container because of what I read on [How can I see which user launched a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50549356/395857), but it looks like you're right.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `docker inspect` will show only the configuration that
the container started with.

Because of the fact that commands like `entrypoint` (or any init script) might change the user, those changes will not be reflected on the `docker inspect` output.

In order to work around this, you can to overwrite the default entrypoint set by the image with 
 `--entrypoint=""` and specify a command like `whoami` or `id` after it.

In your case:

```
docker container run --rm --entrypoint "" jcsilva/docker-kaldi-gstreamer-server whoami
```

**You can see that the output for the image you specified is the `root` user.**

Read more about `entrypoint ""` in [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime).