# What characterizes a Docker image or container as active?

Tags: docker

One can use the command [`docker system df`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180602170331/https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/)) (introduced in Docker 1.13.0) to see docker disk usage, e.g.:

```
username@server:~$ docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE             SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              44                  28                 114.7GB             84.84GB (73%)
Containers          86                  7                  62.43GB             41.67GB (66%)
Local Volumes       2                   1                  0B                  0B
Build Cache                                                0B                  0B
```

What does "active" mean? I.e., what characterizes an image or a container as active?

The Docker [documentation on `docker system df`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180602170331/https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/)) doesn't explain it. The [Docker glossary](https://docs.docker.com/glossary/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180602171845/https://docs.docker.com/glossary/)) doesn't contain the term "active".

I understand that:

- "active" container means that the container is currently running (active containers can be listed with [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) or [equivalently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45254677/395857) [`docker container ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_ls/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it means:

- Images: there is a container that exists using this image
- Containers: container is currently running
- Volumes: there is a container that exists with this volume mounted

Comment: Thanks. If an image is active iff there is a container using it, then how is it possible that in my example (taken from real life) there are more active images (28) than active containers (7)?

Comment: A container can exist that is not currently active. You should (and do) see fewer active images than you do total containers.